# batch script - run command on each file in directory

Tags: batch-file, cmd, foreach, ssconvert

I need to convert some xls files into xlsx files. I can successfully convert one xls file into xlsx by running this command into cmd prompt (windows):

```
ssconvert inputFileName.xls outputFileName.xlsx
```

(ssconvert is a Gnumeric's command-line utility that can convert between different spreadsheet file formats)

I'd like to write a batch file that FOR EACH file in a specified directory runs the command I wrote above, using the current file name both for input and for output filename.

For example, if I have this set of files:

```
c:\directory\file1.xls
c:\directory\file2.xls
c:\directory\file3.xls
```

the output should be

```
c:\directory\file1.xlsx
c:\directory\file2.xlsx
c:\directory\file3.xlsx
```

so the batch pseudo code should be something like

```
directory = c:\directory\
for (fileName in directory)
    ssconvert fileName.xls fileName.xlsx
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you loop in a Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355791/how-do-you-loop-in-a-windows-batch-file)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
for /r %%v in (*.xls) do ssconvert "%%v" "%%vx"
```

a couple have people have asked me to explain this, so:

Part 1: `for /r %%v in (*.xls)`

This part returns an array of files in the current directory that have the `xls` extension. The `%%` may look a little curious. This is basically the special `%` character from command line as used in %PATH% or %TEMP%. To use it in a batch file we need to escape it like so: `%%PATH%%` or `%%TEMP%%`. In this case we are simply escaping the temporary variable `v`, which will hold our array of filenames.

We are using the `/r` switch to search for files recursively, so any matching files in child folders will also be located.

Part 2: `do ssconvert "%%v" "%%vx"`

This second part is what will get executed once per matching filename, so if the following files were present in the current folder:

`c:\temp\mySheet.xls, 
c:\temp\mySheet_yesterday.xls,
c:\temp\mySheet_20160902.xls`

the following commands would be executed:

`ssconvert "c:\temp\mySheet.xls" "c:\temp\mySheet.xlsx"
ssconvert "c:\temp\mySheet_yesterday.xls" "c:\temp\mySheet_yesterday.xlsx"
ssconvert "c:\temp\mySheet_20160902.xls" "c:\temp\mySheet_20160902.xlsx"`

Comment: I could not get it to work with the /r.  Removed that and it was fine.

Comment: @BradIrby I've used it to run a jar-Konverter instead of ssconvert and it was working well, so you might had some issues with your dos cmd.exe ;-).

Comment: FWIW /r means "recursive" (and seemed to work ok here) (the "%%vx" in this instance just means "use %%v and add the letter x after that")

Comment: remember that if you try from command prompt it works with single percent sign while in a batch(cmd) file it needs the double percent sign!

Comment: Why didn't you explain the command so that others like me can make better use of it...?

Comment: you should add some explanation to what you actually did. People viit stackoverflow to learn, not to copy - at least they should

Comment: Is there a way to remove the old extension ? Because "%%v" is the whole name

Comment: @Phoenix you could use `"%%~nv"` to just get the filename without extension

Comment: @paul could you point me to some resource about `~nv` syntax?

Comment: @Wodzu https://stackoverflow.com/a/54963037/1280587

Answer (score 32):

Actually this is pretty easy since Windows Vista. Microsoft added the command [FORFILES](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc753551%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

in your case

```
forfiles /p c:\directory /m *.xls /c "cmd /c ssconvert @file @fname.xlsx"
```

the only weird thing with this command is that forfiles automatically adds double quotes around @file and @fname. but it should work anyway

Comment: Note that the quotes may mess with other commands, [but can be removed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32491884/5475891)

Answer (score 17):

you can run something like this (paste the code bellow in a .bat, or if you want it to run interractively replace the `%%` by `%` :

```
for %%i in (c:\directory\*.xls) do ssconvert %%i %%i.xlsx
```

If you can run powershell it will be :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\directory -filter *.xls | foreach {ssconvert $($_.FullName) $($_.baseName).xlsx }
```

Comment: Does the first command work as %%i already has .xls extension so you'll be converting to .xlsxlsx

Comment: What if my directory has a space character in it. How to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

I am doing similar thing to compile all the c files in a directory. 
for iterating files in different directory try this.

```
set codedirectory=C:\Users\code
for /r  %codedirectory% %%i in (*.c) do 
( some GCC commands )
```