# How to get rid of enclosing double-quotes in the expanded `forfiles` variables?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, quotes

The `forfiles` command establishes several variables, indicated by a leading `@`, which return data concerning the currently iterated item to the loop body.

All the variables related to the path and name of the iterated item return the value enclosed in `""`. Those are: `@file`, `@fname`, `@ext`, `@path` and `@relpath`.

So: how can you get rid of the enclosing double-quotes?

---

For example, the following code returns relative paths to text files in the given root directory:

```
forfiles /P "C:\root" /M "*.txt" /C "cmd /C echo @relpath"
```

Assuming that `C:\root` contains two files `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`, the output will be:

```
".\file1.txt"
".\file2.txt"
```

However, I want the list of files without the surrounding `""`.

I am working on Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One approach is to nest a `for %I` loop within the `forfiles` and use the `%~I` expansion -- use this code in a Command Prompt window:

```
forfiles /P "C:\root" /M "*.txt" /C "cmd /Q /C for %I in (@relpath) do echo %~I"
```

To use that code within a batch file you must double the `%`-signs:

```
forfiles /P "C:\root" /M "*.txt" /C "cmd /Q /C for %%I in (@relpath) do echo %%~I"
```

The returned list of files will be (relying on the sample files from the original question):

```
.\file1.txt
.\file2.txt
```

---

Another variant is to nest another `forfiles` in the body of the initial one, because `forfiles` removes (non-escaped) double-quotes within given strings like the command line after `/C`:

```
forfiles /P "C:\root" /M "*.txt" /C "cmd /C forfiles /P @path\.. /M @file /C \"cmd /C echo @relpath\""
```

Or alternatively (the doubled inner `forfiles` is intentional, this works around a bug -- see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26990159/5047996)):

```
forfiles /P "C:\root" /M "*.txt" /C "forfiles forfiles /P @path\.. /M @file /C \"cmd /C echo @relpath\""
```

The inner `forfiles` will enumerate exactly one item, which is the one passed over by the outer loop. Since `@relpath` is already expanded when the inner loop is executed, the quotes are removed as they are not escaped.

So the returned list of files looks like (again taking the sample files from the original question):

```
.\file1.txt

.\file2.txt
```

The additional line-break between the lines is generated by `forfiles`. You can avoid that using redirection (dismiss `forfiles` output, but display only the `echo` output in the console window):

```
> nul forfiles /P "C:\root" /M "*.txt" /C "cmd /C forfiles /P @path\.. /M @file /C 0x22cmd /C > con echo @relpath0x22"
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for me.  `FORFILES /P "E:\archives" /M *.* /S /D -1 /C "cmd /Q /C FOR %I IN (@path) DO ECHO %~I"` just gives me a "~I was unexpected at this time." error for each line.

Comment: Did you double the `%`-signs as I said in the first sentence of my answer? Regard that you can use single `%`-signs only when you try the code directly in a Command Prompt window...

Comment: Ahh!  Totally missed that.  I have already down-voted and would change my vote but SO will not allow it until it's edited.  Can you either bold that comment in the answer or make another example right below it for batch files so it stands out and allows me to upvote?

Comment: No use for me though, I want to use both \@file and \@path in the target call forfiles is useful over for because I can get both of these. I get the same error of "cannot find the file specified" and all their examples use echo

Comment: Nesting a `for` loop over `@path` should work: `for %I in (@path) do echo "%~I" = @path, "%~nxI" = @file`

Answer (score 2):

I remove the quotes like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
GOTO START

 usage: 
 script.bat "*.txt" "c:\Documents"
 script.bat "*.txt"
 script.bat
 If no arguments added it will crawl the current directory with wildcard mask (*)
 Avoid root directory (c:\) because too many sub directories for the output console.

 :START
IF "%~2"=="" (SET "_FD=%CD%") ELSE (SET "_FD=%~2")
IF "%~1"=="" (SET "_MA=*") ELSE (SET "_MA=%~1")

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in (
        `forfiles /p %_FD% /s /m %_MA% /C "cmd /c ECHO @relpath"`
    ) DO (
    SET "myfile=%%~A"
    ECHO !myfile:~2!
)
ENDLOCAL   
GOTO :EOF
```

results:

```
thumbnails\A0-1.jpg
thumbnails\new folder\img.jpg
```

Comment: This did the trick for me, Thanks!.  I edited mine a little bit.  On the `ECHO !myfile:~2!` line I changed mine to be `ECHO !myfile!` for a full path with no quotes.

Comment: again only uses @relpath and just echos rather than call something that uses it..