# YUI Compressor Minify all JS in a specific folder

Tags: javascript, css, yui, minify, yui-compressor

is there a way to minify all the JS file into a specific folder and output it into another file path? because currently i'm using a single process like this:

```
java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar "C:\QG\Website\YUI\dev\jqueryMain.js" -o "C:\QG\Website\YUI\prod\jqueryMain.min.js"
```

im using Win 10

Comment: Try using a `for` command to run the command on each file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237548/batch-script-run-command-on-each-file-in-directory

`for /r %%file in (*.js) do java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar "%%file" -o "C:\QG\Website\YUI\prod\%%~nfile.min.js"`

See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215501/batch-remove-file-extension

Comment: Yes , Now it's working! but I can't minify a specific folder