# How to show only filenames without extensions using dir command

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I'm trying to list out file names excluding their extension,

How I want it:

```
File1
File2
File3
```

How it currently is:

```
File1.txt
File2.txt
File3.txt
```

I tried using

```bat
@echo off
dir /A:-D /B
pause
```

but it isn't working. I tried it in both a batch file and in command prompt.

Am I using the right command?

Comment: Solved! Thank you all for your help.

Comment: If you solved this your own problem *without the help of any of the below answers*, then consider answering your own way including the way you solved your problem. Else, accept the answer that helped you to solve it.

Answer (score 19):

### Use FOR and ECHO to achieve this

For example, assuming the extension is always `.txt`:

```bat
for %f  in ("*.txt") do @echo %~nf
```

Instead of using DIR, we are using the FOR command to go through the list and sending each one to ECHO, with the "~n" option inserted into the %f, to cause the extension to be not shown.

An alternative is

```bat
FORFILES /c "cmd /c echo @fname"
```

However with this I get quotation marks around each output filename, which isn't what you want.

### If running inside a batch file, you need to double the %'s for variables

```bat
for %%f in ("*.txt") do @echo %%~nf
```

### If you need to handle multiple file extensions

As long the directory doesn't contain any subdirectories whose names have an extension, you can generalise the `*.txt` to `*.*`:

```bat
for %f in ("*.*") do @echo %~nf
```

### If you may have some filenames with only an extension

Where the file has an extension but nothing before it, e.g. `.gitignore`, the resulting empty `ECHO` command will output an inane message, such as `ECHO is on.`  To avoid this ruining your onward plans, you can filter out lines containing `ECHO is`, with the `FIND` command and the `/V` option:

```bat
for %f in ("*.*") do @echo %~nf | find /v "ECHO is"
```

If your local language causes DOS to output something other than `ECHO is` then this filtering will not work. And it will miss any file that happens to contain `ECHO is` in the filename.

### To search subdirectories too, add '/R' to the 'for'

```bat
for /R %f in ("*.png") do @echo %~nf | find /v "ECHO is"
```

### Conclusion

This is all crazy, of course, but this is the agonising price we pay for using Batch language instead of an actual sensible language. I am like an alcoholic, promising to all and sundry that I will never write a line of Batch code again, and then finding myself coming back to do so again, sheepishly.

Comment: This, doesn't achieve what the OP wants: it will skip hidden and system files (about first way) and the second will find also directories. The third way won't work because it should be `%%f`.

Comment: The last option put a % in front of each output filename, but worked as expected (for my needs) when I removed a % from %%~nf

Comment: Thanks @hshah, I have fixed! On the command line we can just type, "for %f", but in a batch file, it must be "for %%f".  double-beep is also correct: the first way misses the hidden and system files, and the second unwantedly captures directories.

Comment: works good but not on subfolder

Comment: subfolder searching added at your request @White  8-)

Answer (score 4):

It'll be much easier in PowerShell

```powershell
(Get-ChildItem -File).BaseName
```

or

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -File | ForEach-Object { $_.BaseName }
```

[`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6) can be replaced with the aliases `ls`, `gci` or `dir`, `-File` can be changed to `-af` and [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object?view=powershell-6) can be replaced with `%` so the shortest you can go is `(ls -af).BaseName`

So from cmd you can run either of these to achieve the purpose

```bat
powershell -Com "(ls -File).BaseName"
powershell -C (ls^ -File).BaseName
powershell (ls^ -af).BaseName
```

Comment: The examples above assume you're using at least Windows 8, or have specifically installed PowerShell v3+. Using PowerShell 2, which is part of Windows 7 you'd need to use: `Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { -Not $_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach-Object { $_.BaseName }`. This would mean from a batch file you'd need at least, `@PowerShell -NoP "Ls|?{!$_.PSIsContainer}|%%{$_.BaseName}"`

Comment: @Compo thanks for your comment. In that case you can reduce to command to `ls *.* |% { $_.BaseName }` if folders never have a dot in their names and file always do

Comment: Of course you could, but it's important to note, that on any PC,  the vast majority of directories aren't named/created by the user, so knowing in advance whether there's any named using a dot is unlikely. Also as you're removing extensions it would be impossible to tell the  directories from the files in the resulting list, _after all its usually the extension that identifies one from the other_.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Eureka's answer, the vanilla `dir` command cannot achieve what you're looking for.

```
C:\Users\jacob>dir /?
Displays a list of files and subdirectories in a directory.

DIR [drive:][path][filename] [/A[[:]attributes]] [/B] [/C] [/D] [/L] [/N]
  [/O[[:]sortorder]] [/P] [/Q] [/R] [/S] [/T[[:]timefield]] [/W] [/X] [/4]

  [drive:][path][filename]
              Specifies drive, directory, and/or files to list.

  /A          Displays files with specified attributes.
  attributes   D  Directories                R  Read-only files
               H  Hidden files               A  Files ready for archiving
               S  System files               I  Not content indexed files
               L  Reparse Points             -  Prefix meaning not
  /B          Uses bare format (no heading information or summary).
  /C          Display the thousand separator in file sizes.  This is the
              default.  Use /-C to disable display of separator.
  /D          Same as wide but files are list sorted by column.
  /L          Uses lowercase.
  /N          New long list format where filenames are on the far right.
  /O          List by files in sorted order.
  sortorder    N  By name (alphabetic)       S  By size (smallest first)
               E  By extension (alphabetic)  D  By date/time (oldest first)
               G  Group directories first    -  Prefix to reverse order
  /P          Pauses after each screenful of information.
  /Q          Display the owner of the file.
  /R          Display alternate data streams of the file.
  /S          Displays files in specified directory and all subdirectories.
  /T          Controls which time field displayed or used for sorting
  timefield   C  Creation
              A  Last Access
              W  Last Written
  /W          Uses wide list format.
  /X          This displays the short names generated for non-8dot3 file
              names.  The format is that of /N with the short name inserted
              before the long name. If no short name is present, blanks are
              displayed in its place.
  /4          Displays four-digit years

Switches may be preset in the DIRCMD environment variable.  Override
preset switches by prefixing any switch with - (hyphen)--for example, /-W.
```

Additionally, as an alternative to the suggestion to use `("*.txt")`, if your file list includes multiple extensions you might either exclude different extensions *or* use `*.*` to get all files with a `.` in the name. Play around with that glob to get what you want out of it.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with a `dir` command and a `for` loop:

```bat
@echo off

for /F "delims= eol=" %%A IN ('dir /A-D /B') do echo %%~nA
```

If you want the **full path** without the extension, try:

```bat
@echo off

for /F "delims= eol=" %%A IN ('dir /A-D /B') do echo %%~dpnA
```

For cmd one-line:

```bat
for /F "delims= eol=" %A IN ('dir /A-D /B') do echo %~nA
```

And for the **full path** without the extension, try:

```bat
for /F "delims= eol=" %A IN ('dir /A-D /B') do echo %~dpnA
```

These small programs, loop through all the files in the folder except directories, and `echo` only the filenames/full paths without the extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
dir -Name -File
```

This is for PowerShell

Comment: `dir: invalid option -- 'e'`

Comment: does not suppress the extensions.

Comment: did you even try this? More than 2 years after my powershell answer and this still gets it wrong