# Is there a way to loop in a batch file without gotos?

Tags: batch-file, goto

I'm fairly new to batch scripting, and I need to write a pretty simple .bat file that will loop through a directory. I know how to do it pretty easily using the goto command:

```
@echo off
:BEGIN
::set variable to data in first file
::do operations on file...
IF ::another file exists in the directory
   ::increment to next file
   GOTO BEGIN
ELSE
   GOTO END
:END
cls
```

The problem is that's the only way I can think of to do it. I know goto's are generally very frowned upon to use, so I was wondering if anyone knows another way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Batch is sort of the exception to the "don't use goto" rule, since in most cases, avoiding the use of a Goto will actually make your code more complex and harder to read. Just make sure your labels are consistent, legible, etc.

Comment: You can use a `FOR` loop.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355791/batch-file-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the echo.... with your desired command.
From the Command prompt:

`for /R %A in (*.*) do echo.%A`

In a bat file

```
for /R %%A in (*.*) do echo.%%A
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done just for the current folder too.  The %%a metavariable is case sensitive and I choose to use lower case.  The script will exit and quit when all files are processed.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
type "%%a"
pause
)
```