# how to run a recurrsion in a DOS command

Tags: batch-file, dos

> I am using this command to fetch the list of folders. But the problem
>   is i have to multiple times. The folder structure is
>   signcollections\0022. the last value should keep on changing until it
>   has folders. please help to run a loop as this is first time i am
>   using DOS command.

dir /b "0022"> f.txt

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355791/how-do-you-loop-in-a-windows-batch-file

Comment: Try below code and check if the output is what you intended , then you can just redirect the same to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Run the below command from command prompt and make sure you are in path required path signcollections , below command will print all files in the folders and sub folders

```
for /d %x in (*) do ( dir  "%x" /b )
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP does not want the `/R` option. He is only asking to list all the direct child folders, not the recursive grandchild (etc) folders.

Comment: @ dbenham thanks for the suggestion , i have changed my answer :)