# using for/if/else statement in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have gone through many questions, but not able to make my code work.
just want to use if/else statement

I have three products i.e. GMAXGateway,PositionMessaging,RensburgGateway for which I need to perform same action, and for rest three same.

I tried if/else/for but of no success

Original code is below

```
%3\mqsicreatebar.exe -data "%1" -b "%2" -cleanbuild -a %product%
```

I have tried below, and many other examples given on websites

`For %%A IN (GMAXGateway,PositionMessaging,RensburgGateway)DO (%3\mqsicreatebar.exe -data "%1" -b "%2" -cleanbuild -a %product% -l integrationemm commonemm)
For %%A IN (OneTISGateway,AccountMessaging,SecurityMessaging)DO (%3\mqsicreatebar.exe -data "%1" -b "%2" -cleanbuild -a %product%)`

Was wondering how to fix the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you loop in a Windows batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355791/how-do-you-loop-in-a-windows-batch-file)

Comment: When in doubt just 1) google `batch-file for` and so on 2) in the Command Prompt console type `for /?` and so on.

Comment: I have already tried that....but of no help

Comment: You're using an incorrect variable name, use `%%a` for example.

Comment: Try `-a %%A` in your loop instead of `-a %product%`

Comment: There must be a _space_ between `DO` and `(`!

Answer (score 0):

Command processor is not tolerant on leaving out spaces or putting round brackets on next line.

Open a command prompt window, execute the command `for /?` and read the output help, all display pages, not just first one.

```
@echo off
for %%A in (GMAXGateway PositionMessaging RensburgGateway) do (
    "%~3\mqsicreatebar.exe" -data "%~1" -b "%~2" -cleanbuild -a %%A -l integrationemm commonemm
)
for %%A in (OneTISGateway,AccountMessaging,SecurityMessaging) do "%~3\mqsicreatebar.exe" -data "%~1" -b "%~2" -cleanbuild -a %%A
```

The product strings can be separated with a space or comma.

There must be a space between `)` and `do`.

`(` marking begin of body of **FOR** loop must be on same line as `for`, loop variable, `in`, list of strings, and `do` with a space between `do` and `(`.

`)` marking end of body should be also always on a separate line.

For a single command it is possible to omit `(` and `)` and write the command on same line after `do` as done on second **FOR** loop. But in general the code is better readable when using the syntax as in first **FOR** loop also for single commands in body of loop.

And of course the loop variable must be used inside body of the loop and not a different variable not defined at all.