# How do I make a series of files run through a software as its input using batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I have 100 files, for example `c1.mat`, `c2.mat`, ..., `c100.mat`

I want to loop through each file to run a simulation within a software, taking one file at a time.

How do I write a batch script for the same?

```
@echo off 
title conductivity changes

start fem.srn -e c1.mat
```

This script opens the program. But does not take the file `c1.mat` as a variable.

Comment: Duplicate question I believe: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355791/how-do-you-loop-in-a-windows-batch-file).

Comment: Is the order of files relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This for loop might work.

```
for /l %%a in (1,1,100) do (
    start fem.srn -e c%%a.mat
    timeout 5
    rem timeout needed?
)
```

Comment: How do I save out outputs and then exit the program?

Comment: Outputs of the mat program, or do you want to get user input in the batch file to work with later?

Answer (score 0):

For a bash script (sorry misread the original question when I saw 'batch')

```
for file in *
do
   echo $file
done
```

Replace the echo command above with your command.  you can also replace * with something like c*.mat or *.mat  Also you can use a word other than file.