# wget: batch download with increment

Tags: bash, macos, download, wget

I have this situation: I want to download a bunch of files named like this:

```
683482, 684483, 685484, 686485, 687486, 688487, 689488, 690489, 691490, 692491, ...
```

As you can see, the files are numbered with an increment of 1001. So, what's the easiest way to do a batch download?

Answer (score 1):

```
ECHO OFF
CLS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /L %%A IN (683482,1001, 692491) DO (
    SET stringWget=wget %%A
    !stringWget!
)
```

I'll go step by step:

`ECHO OFF` prevents windows command line from displaying every command on the command-prompt (this is optional; But, looks clean).

`CLS` clear screen; This clears command prompt's console display. It [does not clear the temporary environment variables or command history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLS_(command)).

`SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` is used for non-blocking statements and is Windows specific; When we use `%ENVIRONMENTVARIABLE%` , we are implying blocking statement and when we use `!ENVIRONMENTVARIABLE!` we are implying non-blocking statement (meaning, in a loop, we see updated values of `%A` instead of repeating what `%A` had when entering loop). We use `%%` instead of `%`in batch files.

`FOR` loop's syntax can be found in reference.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3541415

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
#!/bin/bash  
for i in {683482..1000000..1001}
    do
        wget $i
    done
```

Comment: or `for ((i=683482; i<=1000000; i=i+1001))`

Comment: I'm not expert in bash programming. May be this works or not i dont know.

Comment: `wget <your URL>/$i`
Also, wget accepts more than one URL argument. For a faster download, add up the URLs in a variable and then execute wget just once. Just one DNS lookup and likely there will be a persistent connection.