# Search for files in a batch script and process those files?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to do some things during the pre-build phase of a visual studio project.  Specifically, I'm trying to execute some commands on all *.resx files within the project.  Here is what I have but it doesn't work when the files/directory path have a space in them.  How do I get around these spaces?

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /B /S *.resx') do echo "%%a"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate all files in a directory using a 'for' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138497/iterate-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You know that `for` can also run recursively over directories?

```
for /r %%x in (*.resx) do echo "%%x"
```

Much easier than fiddling with delimiters and saves you from running `dir`.

Comment: This looks like the cleanest solution.  I knew there had to be a trick.  I'm just so used to *nix scripting where things are so much easier.  Thanks you all for the info.

Comment: Well, it's hardly more convoluted than find/xargs, imho.

Answer (score 4):

Stick with the For text parser of the shell

```
for /f "delims=|" %%a in ('dir /B /S *.resx') do echo "%%a"
```

just add a delims option (for a delim character which obviously couldn't exist), et voila!

In the absense of this delims option, /f will do what it is supposed to, i.e. parse the input by splitting it at every space or tabs sequence.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [findutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm) for Windows - it includes both "find" and "xargs"

Answer (score 3):

You are running into inadvertant use of the default space delimeter.  You can fix that by resetting the delims like so:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /S *.resx') do echo "%%a"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also install cygwin to get a full-blown Unix-esque shell, which comes with the trusty old "find" command, plus a bunch of other tools. For example,

```
find . -name "*.resx" | xargs grep MyProjectName
```

Comment: And you make your whole build depend on the existence of cygwin. Not very nice. Let alone the fact that it's very un-needed for this task.

Answer (score 1):

To generate a simple file list of all the relevant files for later processing

```
@echo create a results file…
if exist results.txt (del results.txt)
echo. >NUL 2>results.txt

@echo minimal recursive subdirectory search for filespec...
dir /s /a /b "*.resx" >>results.txt
```