# bat function to find a file in folder and subfolders and do something with it.

Tags: windows, batch-file, find, batch-processing

I need to find all files with specific filename(for example main.css) in folder and all subfolders and then do something with it(eg. rename, move, delete, add text line, etc)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search for files in a batch script and process those files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447703/search-for-files-in-a-batch-script-and-process-those-files)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
for /R %f in (main.css) do @echo "%f"
```

Naturally you would replace `echo` with whatever it is you wish to do to the file. You can use wildcards if you need to:

```
for /R %f in (*.css) do @echo "%f"
```

Answer (score 11):

While this will traverse the directory tree:

```
for /R %f in (main.css) do @echo "%f"
```

It doesn't actually match file names.  That is, if you have a tree:

```
    DirectoryA
        A1
        A2
```

the **for /R** operation will give %f of *DirectoryA/main.css*, then *DirectoryA/A1/main.css* and so on even if  main.css is not in any of those directories.  So to be sure that there really is a file (or directory) you should do this:

```
for /R %f in (main.css) do @IF EXIST %f @echo "%f"
```

Also, be aware that you do need to quote the file name because if the path or file contains spaces the directory walking may blow up.

The above is, at least, how it is working in Windows 8.