# Grouping multiple split-up RAR archives by folder with Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

Say I have a folder "C:\pokepoke" with archives like:

```
trequetry.part01.rar
trequetry.part02.rar
trequetry.part03.rar
```

and

```
replokitro.part01.rar
replokitro.part02.rar
replokitro.part03.rar
replokitro.part04.rar
```

and so on. How can I make it so the first set of archives ends up in `C:\pokepoke\trequetry` and the second in `C:\pokepoke\replokitro` and so on. So basically filter on X.partX.rar or something in that direction.

I am trying to batch-create recovery files with `par2` for lots of split-up archives so in addition to my main question, I would also like to find out how to perform a for-each on all subfolders in `C:\pokepoke` so I can run the following code on it once all archives are moved to their respective folders:

```
FOR /R %%g IN (.) DO C:\WINDOWS\par2.exe c -r10 -s384000 "%%g\%%~ng.par2" "%%g\*"
del /q *.par2
```

Comment: These are nice questions, however they should be posted separately, in my opinion.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138497/batch-scripting-iterating-over-files-in-a-directory/138581#138581) might help you with the second question, the one about `foreach` (subfolder).

Comment: @Andriy That's a very useful link for me Andriy, thanks. I "fixed" my main problem by altering the winrar batch script to automatically place the files in a subfolder after archiving, but I'm still hoping for an answer on how to do this with already existing archives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help you with your first question, the following script worked for me:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "origloc=D:\path\to\archives"
FOR %%F IN ("%origloc%\*.part*.rar") DO CALL :process "%%F"
GOTO :EOF

:process
CALL :checkpath "%~dpn1"
MOVE %1 "%subfolder%" >NUL
GOTO :EOF

:checkpath
SET "subfolder=%~dpn1"
IF NOT EXIST "%subfolder%\" MKDIR "%subfolder%"
GOTO :EOF
```

This script searches for `*.part*.rar` files in the specified folder. It applies the `~dpn` modifier to every name twice to strip the name of the 'double extension' `.partNN.rar`, then uses the resulting name as the subfolder name.

Optionally you could change the first SET command like this:

```
SET "origloc=%~1"
```

to be able to call the script for an arbitrary path, passing the path as a parameter.