# For loop and delims in batch files

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

Can someone please help me understand command file syntax

```
IF "%INPUT_PATH%"=="" (
    echo Searching for latest test results in: %TEST_RESULTS%
    FOR /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /O-D /B "%TEST_RESULTS%\*.trx"') DO (
        SET INPUT_PATH=%TEST_RESULTS%\%%~ni
        GOTO :DoneInputPath
) )
```

I get that it first checks if INPUT_PATH variable is empty and if it is empty then enters into an inner for loop, I am lost otherwise

specifically

1. `FOR /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /O-D /B "%TEST_RESULTS%\*.trx"')`
2. `SET INPUT_PATH=%TEST_RESULTS%\%%~ni`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Most of the information you need is available in the built-in help, though it can be daunting if you are new to batch programming. For example, type `HELP FOR` or `FOR /?` from the command prompt to get help on the FOR command.

**Explanation:**

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /O-D /B "%TEST_RESULTS%\*.trx"') ...
```

The DIR command lists all of the `*.TRX` files within the `%TEST_RESULTS%` path. The `/B` option gives the brief format (file names only). The `/O-D` option sorts the files by last modified date descending (newest first).

The FOR /F command has three modes, depending on the format of the IN() clause. The fact that the IN() clause is enclosed in single quotes means that FOR /F treats the contents as a command, and processes the output of the command, one line at a time. The `"delims="` option means do not parse into tokens (preserve each entire line). So each line is iteratively loaded into the `%%i` variable. The `%%i` variable only exists within the context of the FOR command.

```
SET INPUT_PATH=%TEST_RESULTS%\%%~ni
```

I think you know what most of this command does. The only "unusual" aspect is the `%%~ni` syntax. That syntax expands the value of `%%i` into the base file name only, without any extension.

```
GOTO :DoneInputPath
```

The GOTO causes the FOR loop to abort after the first iteration. This means that INPUT_PATH will be set to the name of the most recently modified `*.trx` file, since it sorted to the top.

If the GOTO were not there, then the end result would be the oldest `*.trx` file instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this, explanation is in the comment:

```
IF NOT DEFINED INPUT_PATH (
    echo Searching for latest test results in: %TEST_RESULTS%
    REM dir /OD means older files first and the youngest last, the last remains in INPUT_PATH; use "%%~nxi" for file name + file extension
    FOR /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /OD /B "%TEST_RESULTS%\*.trx"') DO SET "INPUT_PATH=%TEST_RESULTS%\%%~ni"
)
```