# How to get filenames by traversing a folder in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

```
for %%s in (Y:\ACS\data\rtr\CHS_cp0ex\dataFiles\Reported\TTFILE*.*) do (
 Y:\ACS\data\rtr\CHS_cp0ex\dataFiles\Reported\deasn9.exe -a      Y:\ACS\data\rtr\CHS_cp0ex\dataFiles\Reported\cme20MSS13a_itu -b  %%s   >Y:\ACS\data\rtr\CHS_cp0ex\dataFiles\tmp\%%s:~ns.txt
)
```

i tried to get filenames from folder `Y:\ACS\data\rtr\CHS_cp0ex\dataFiles\Reported\`

but \%%s:~ns cannot get filename ,why?

Comment: Use `dir`, that's how you get filenames in dos.

Comment: i want get the filenames in script as var.

Comment: Well, my friend, you should learn to write better titles. Now edit your **question's title** and make it clear what you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [batch scripting iterating over files in a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138497/batch-scripting-iterating-over-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: Pure dos is MSDOS which doesn't support foldernames or filenames over 8.3 characters.  Your example shows that you are using Windows CMD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set "dataFiles=Y:\ACS\data\rtr\CHS_cp0ex\dataFiles"

for %%s in ("%dataFiles%\Reported\TTFILE*.*") do (
    "%dataFiles%\Reported\deasn9.exe" -a "%dataFiles%\Reported\cme20MSS13a_itu" -b "%%~fs" >"%dataFiles%\tmp\%%~ns.txt"
)
```

There was a lot of paths. I've replaced them with a variable, but this is not needed.

Now, the references to files in the `for` command variable

`%%s` will hold a reference to the file. Full path, relative or no path to the file will or will not be included depending on how the set of files is indicated in the `for` command

`%%~ns` The name, without extension, of the file

`%%~nxs` The name, with extension, of the file

`%%~fs` The full path to the file. Drive, folders, filename and extension.

For a full list of the different modifiers, see `for /?`

Comment: Y:\>("Y:\ACS\data\rtr\CHS_cp0ex\dataFiles\Reported\deasn9.exe" -a "Y:\ACS\data\rtr\CHS_cp0ex\dataFiles\Reported\cme20MSS13a_itu" -b "Y:\ACS\data\rtr\CHS_cp0ex\dataFiles\Reported\TTFILE.201401101630282600"  1>"Y:\ACS\data\rtr\CHS_cp0ex\dataFiles\tmp\TTFILE.txt" )
The system cannot execute the specified program.

Y:\>("Y:\ACS\data\rtr\CHS_cp0ex\dataFiles\Reported\deasn9.exe" -a "Y:\ACS\data\rtr\CHS_cp0ex\dataFiles\Reported\cme20MSS13a_itu" -b "Y:\ACS\data\rtr\CHS_cp0ex\dataFiles\Reported\TTFILE.201401101630422601"  1>"Y:\ACS\data\rtr\CHS_cp0ex\dataFiles\tmp\TTFILE.txt" )

Comment: why all filenames is TTFILE.txt

Comment: i also use %%~nxs the same an belows

Comment: @user3143869: `The system cannot execute ...` Path to the executable is translated from your code. If it is not there, adapt as needed.

Comment: @user3143869: `all filenames are TTFILE.txt` : Well, from your output, all files are named `TTFILE`, the only difference is in the extension, so, in `"%dataFiles%\tmp\%%~ns.txt"` change `%%~ns.txt` to `%%~nxs.txt`

Comment: i find it that the reason of it cannot run is that i run it in Pure DOS. but i thank you very much.

Answer (score -2):

`Dir` is what you are looking for. You sound like a unix user.

Comment: i want get the filenames in script as var.