# Batch file to convert all pdf to text (with xpdf)

Tags: pdf, batch-file, xpdf

I would like to run a batch conversion in a folder with full of pdf files. I have using xPDF and this is the command prompt for a single file:

c:\Test\pdftotext -layout firstpdftoconvert.pdf firstpdfconverted.txt

Could somebody help please to do it in one go (convert all the pdf files only) using a batch file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I don't enter the converted text file name, it will be automatically the same as the pdf's name, so this command is enough :c:\Test\pdftotext -layout firstpdftoconvert.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combining your question with [this answer iterating over files of a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/138538/63733):

```
for /r %i in (*.pdf) do "c:\Test\pdftotext" -layout "%i"
```

This will work on all pdf files in the *current* directory.

Be sure to double the `%` signs if you run this from a batch file.

Comment: Thank you! I have a small problem, I don't know if it will work... I would like to run this batch file on a network drive, not a local hard drive, and with the same code it's not working. Any ideas? This is the command I try to run: for /r %%i in (*.pdf) do pdftotext -layout %%i (works locally, doesn't on the network)

Comment: You may try mapping the network folder to a drive letter (Z:\ for example), and then execute the command from the drive letter.

Comment: It is mapped, the location of the folder: g:\PORTABLES\Internal Order Label\CalCerts\pdftotext.exe    Any ideas?

Comment: Look at the edited code above - it supports long paths and filenames now.