# Converting txt file to pdf file in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, pdf, text, command-line

Is there any way to convert a `.txt` file to a `.pdf` file using batch script?

I tried researching but all are only pdf to txt. (e.g. [Batch file to convert all pdf to text (with xpdf)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307682/batch-file-to-convert-all-pdf-to-text-with-xpdf)).

I do not mind downloading any software to convert txt to pdf but I wish to download command-based software as I wanted to do use batch script.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Somebody evaluated a couple of ways how to print text files to PDF using any of the Software PDF printers out there: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/printfiles.php