# FFMPEG in Windows 7: merge mp4 files from different folders in a batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I would like to concatenate 3 mp4 videos into one avi video for every folder of a directory, with FFMPEG on Windows 7.

I have started this way:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy E:\EA2014\EX14R\EX14R.avi
```

with mylist.txt being:

> ```
> file 'E:\EA2014\EX14R\DCIM\100GOPRO\GOPR0001.MP4' 
> file 'E:\EA2014\EX14R\DCIM\100GOPRO\GP010001.MP4' 
> file 'E:\EA2014\EX14R\DCIM\100GOPRO\GP020001.MP4'
> ```

This works fine. Now, I would like to automate it because I have lots of those folders full of videos to merge.
I tried with this to start with:

```
printf "file '$s'\n" .E\EA2014\EX14R\DCIM\100GOPRO\*.MP4 >> mylist.txt
```

But it tells me that

> "printf is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Is it because I work in Windows? Anyone could help me achieve it in another way?

Needless to say that I am a newbie!

Thanks!

Comment: possibly use a scripting language, or, if you're addicted to batch files, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138497/iterate-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-for-loop might help

Comment: Does each folder contain exactly three MP4 files?  Where does the target filename come from?  Is the target location fixed?

Comment: Each folder contains 3 MP4. Their filename are autogenerated from the camera device (gopro). The target location would change for every folder (eg EX14R, EX15R, EX16R, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This should process each folder under the `E:\EA2014\EX14R` tree and create the .avi file in each individual folder, calling it `myfile.avi`

```
@echo off
for /d /r "E:\EA2014\EX14R" %%a in (*) do (
   if exist "%%a\*.mp4" (
      del mylist.txt 2>nul
      for %%b in ("%%a\*.mp4") do >>mylist.txt echo file '%%b'
      ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy "%%a\myfile.avi"
      del mylist.txt 2>nul
   )
)
```

Comment: Thanks foxidrive. I am getting this error: %%a was unexpected at this time. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you put it in a batch file?  Did you change anything?

Comment: I did put it in a batch file. I just changed the second line to :  for /d /r "E:\EA2014" %%a in (*) do (                             Because the folders containing the mp4 files are all located in EA2014

Comment: Maybe some editing error crept in - I tested the script here in an elementary way and it didn't generate any errors.  Try copy/paste again and put `echo` before the `ffmpeg` and run it as it is.