# How to run an executable on all files in a directory matching a file extension wildcard pattern?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I have a file `testfile.exe` that runs with parameters like below:

```
testfile.exe c:\path1\file.txt 3 c:\path2\file2.txt
```

The second parameter `3` is a sampling factor.

So I run the application with the parameters:

- input file with path
- a sampling factor
- output file with path

What would be needed in a batch file to search in a source directory for all files with a specific file extension and run the command with the input/sample/output parameters?

Comment: This might help you!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138497/iterate-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-for-loop

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
set "SourceFolder=c:\path1"
set "OutputFolder=c:\path2"
set "SampleFactor=1"
for %%a in ("%SourceFolder%\*.ext") do (
    example.exe "%%a" "%SampleFactor%" "%OutputFolder%\%%~na.ext"
)
```

Comment: All file/folder names without or with path containing a space or one of the characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~`` must be enclosed in double quotes. Open a command prompt window, enter `cmd /?` and read the output help pages where on last paragraph on last help page you can read about this list. I modified your not working code to the working code above.