# Replacing strings with batch file command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have many files that are name "12739-5468768.xml", what they have in common is the "12739", inside these files I want to replace every `&` with " AND " and every `</` with nothing. I tried many commands and python command but it doesn't seem to operate on my computer.

```
@echo off
setlocal 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
set "search=&" 
set "replace= AND " 
set "textfile=12739*" 
set "newfile=Output.txt" 
(
  for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do ( 
    set "line=%%i" 
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!" 
    echo(!line!
  )
) > "%newfile%" 
del %textfile% 
rename %newfile% %textfile% 
endlocal
```

Comment: And it just even tell me where it fails, nothing appears.

Comment: I get the error `the file "12739*" can't be found`, that's because FOR/F doesn't accept wildcards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download something called "FART"
then include it in the folder of the batch then do a bat with this code

```
"@echo off
FART -i -r "12739*" "&"  " AND " "
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for a single file
This handles also `!^`, empty lines and lines beginning with `;` in the file content.

```
@echo off
setlocal 

call :replaceFile "12739-5468768.xml" 
exit /b

:replaceFile
set "search=&" 
set "replace= AND " 
set "textfile=%~1" 
set "newfile=%~1.replaced" 
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion 
(
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`findstr /N "^" "%textfile%"`) do ( 
    set "line=%%i" 
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
    set "line=!line:*:=!" 
    if defined line (
      set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
      set "line=!line:</=!"
    )
    (echo(!line!)
    endlocal
  )
) > "%newfile%" 
endlocal
exit /b
```

Comment: does this work for more than one file, I want to be able to do 12739*

Comment: Just found with google [Iterate all files in a directory using a for-loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/138497/463115)

Comment: I downloaded FART and did 
FART -i -r "C:\Desktop\def\12739*.xml" &  AND
But it isnt working for me.

Comment: @jasmine825 How is FART related with my answer?

Comment: @jasmine825 You may accept jeb's answer, for is a working solution for you. you only need some homework to make it work with as many files as you want!! `for /r %%x in  ("12739*.xml") do call :replaceFile "%%x"` as he suggested

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the & Ampersand using the ^ character.

```
@echo off
setlocal 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
set "search=^&" 
set "replace= AND " 
set "textfile=12739*" 
set "newfile=Output.txt" 
(
  for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do ( 
    set "line=%%i" 
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!" 
    echo(!line!
  )
) > "%newfile%" 
del %textfile% 
rename %newfile% %textfile% 
endlocal
```

Comment: Nice idea, but that's wrong. As the search expression is always inside quotes, it must not be escaped

Comment: As said, it can't work. Btw your code will stop at the `for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%)` with the error `the file "12739*" can't be found`

Comment: This removed my whole file.