# can´t find file when iterating files in directory

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have a simply batch that iterates files within a directory as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/138964/2528063):

```
cd "c:/TheDirectory"
for /f %%i in (*) do echo %%i
```

However when I execute this I get the following error:

> Unable to find file *

When I execute this within a shell-promt I get the files within the directory.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Try `%cd%`instead of `*` . Should do the same or am I wrong? Or `!cd!` if needed.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 Witrh `%cd%` I get `Unable to find file C:/TheDirectory`, with `!cd!` I get `Unable to find file "!cd!"`.

Comment: Lose the [`/f`](http://ss64.com/nt/for2.html) flag.

Comment: After a short search I found you have to use `/r` instead of `/f` this will however, include subfolders as well.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, your code does not match the example of the link you referenced. Remove the `/F` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write it like that :

```
@ECHO OFF
cd "c:\Test"
for /r %%i in (*) do echo %%i
pause
```

For more info about [**`FOR /R`**](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) to loop through files (Recurse subfolders)

***EDIT : on 06/09/2016 @19:18***

To show only files without recursion :

```
@echo off
set "Folder=%windir%"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('Dir /A-D /b "%Folder%\*.*"') do echo %Folder%\%%i
pause & exit
```

Comment: Actually I don´t want to recurse into sub-folders.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Check my last edit to show only files on folder without recursion

Comment: For non-recursive enumeration, a standard `for` loop was enough, no there is need for `for /F` and `dir` actually: `for /r %%i in (*) do echo %%i`

Answer (score 1):

For such a basic task/requirement then maybe this is all you need:

```
For %%i In (C:\TheDirectory\*.*) Do Echo %%~nxi
```

Also note the backslash which is common notation in DOS\Win. (you can use doublequotes if your directory has spaces `"C:\The Directory\*.*"`)