# How to convert multiple markdown files at once

Tags: cmd, markdown, multimarkdown

I have a folder with several markdown files and I need to convert them to HTML at once.

This works fine:

```
multimarkdown -b file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

But this doesn't:

```
multimarkdown -b *.txt
```

I get the error in the cmd window:

```
*.txt: Invalid argument
```

I also tried `multimarkdown -b "*.txt"` and `multimarkdown "*.txt" -b`, but still doesn't work.

Maybe I miss something? (I use MultiMarkdown 5.4.0)

Comment: Please indicate the shell you are using to give the commands to the OS. Otherwise this question makes little sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The star syntax is actually part of `bash` which is a unix shell (Mac/Linux), so you I think you won't be able to use it with `cmd` on Windows.

Use PowerShell instead, or write your [own loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138497/iterate-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-for-loop), like:

```
for /r %i in (*.txt) do multimarkdown -b %i
```

Comment: Your solution works, thank you very much. The link is also very useful.