# Batch Iterate every Xth file

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, cmd

Similar to this: [Iterate all files in a directory using a 'for' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138497/iterate-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-for-loop) but insted I need to iterate over every 5th file within the directory? Whats the most clever way to do it? (doesn't need to be a for loop)

Comment: add a counter and do only every 5 iterations

Comment: thx but I would prefer using just one line and not a 'complex' if statment

Comment: You're not going to get a "simple" solution to this. That would require built-in functionality of either `for` or `dir` to be able to do this, and neither one can because that would require doing things to "every few files" to be a normal thing that people do. It's not. Use the counter variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A one liner

```dos
set x=0 & for %a in (*) do @((>nul 2>nul set /a "x=(x+1)%5,1/x") || echo %a)
```

It will

- Initialize a counter (`set x=0`)
- For each file in the folder (`for %a in (*) do`)
- Hiding the output of the calc and any error (`>nul 2>nul`), increase the counter and get the remainder of the value divided by 5 (`set /a x=(x+1)%5`). This will set the value of the counter to 1 for the first file, 2 for the second, ... and 0 for the fifth file ( `5/5 = 1 with a reminder of 0`)
- Inside the same `set /a` we also try to calculate `1/x`. This will fail with an error (hiden, the reason for the `2>nul`) when `x=0` (fifth file)
- The conditional operator `||` (execute next command when the previous fails) executes the `echo %a` when the previous `1/x` fails

Comment: upvoting for `,1/x`. Would upvote again for not needing delayed expansion.

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand why everyone wants a one-liner to solve a complex task. But anyhow, here you are:

```
cmd /v:on /c "@for /f "tokens=1,* delims=[]" %a in ('dir /b /a-d^|find /n /v ""') do @set /a "x=%a %5">nul&@if !x!==0 @echo %a: %b"
```

Comment: thx sorry I expressed myself wrongly. I hoped there is a way to add an step variable (or s.th. like this) therfore I was looking for a "one liner". I didn't thought that it is not that easy. But your code works perfectly fine. So much appreciation for it.