# Create thumbnail from a video directory using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, thumbnails

I have a project that requires me to produce a thumbnail from 2000 videos, i researched for a tool on the net and found that ffmpeg can do it, however i could not find a sample that will demonstrate how to work on a directory of videos and run on it do create thumbnail for all the videos, can any one point to a good sample
Thanks Shimon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is too broad, FFmpeg is not a magic tool, has nothing to do with directories, so your task will be a little bit more complicated here.

To extract a frame from a video, here's a command you can start with:

```
ffmpeg -i <INPUT_FILE.EXT> -filter_complex "select=between(t\,10\,20)*eq(pict_type\,I)" -vframes 1 -f image2 <OUTPUT.jpg>
```

This command will extract an I-frame from the video between 10 to 20 seconds. You may want to extend your filtergraph with a [`scale`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-scale-1) and [`crop`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-crop) filter to make your thumbnails the same format.

All you need to do is to put this command in a script that loops trough your video library. Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks' do you have a sample script to execute the process? or do you know where i can found one

Comment: Since I don't know your folder structure or whatsoever, I assume that all videos are dumped in the same directory.
In this case the loop would be something like this:

`for /r %%i in (*) do (
  ffmpeg -i %%i -filter_complex "select=between(t\,10\,20)*eq(pict_type\,I)" -vframes 1 -f image2 %%~ni.jpg
)`

You need to put this in a batch file, of course. Here's a related question how to loop trough files in windows batch: **[--link--](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138497/iterate-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-for-loop)**

Have a good hacking!