# Findstr return entire line, is line contains X

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I have been searching the internet for 2 hours now and cant find what I am looking for.

Basically, I want to script searching the entire drive for specific files.

Best way I found to do this is by outputting all folders and files to an output file with `dir /s`.  Then, I use `findstr` to compare my search parameters file against the `dir` output.  The search works...but it only puts out the specific thing it found.

Results I get are

```
notepad.exe
download.bat
```

Results I want are

```
c:\windows\notepad.exe
c:\download.bat
```

. . .Or if you have code that will just search the drive for said things, then thats perfect.  I'd actually want just the path, instead of the whole line found in `dir /s`.

either way, heres some code I was playing with.

```
@echo off

set dir_out=c:\dir_output.txt
set search=C:\in.txt
set out=c:\Match_Output.txt

echo delelting old %search% file
if exist  %search% del %search% /f

echo delelting old %out% file
if exist  %out% del %out% /f

echo delelting old %dir_out% file
if exist  %dir_out% del %dir_out% /f

echo creating new %search% file
echo notepad.exe >> %search%
echo download.bat >> %search%

echo changing to root directory
cd\

echo outputing entire c:\ into log file
dir /s >> %dir_out%

echo matching log file
findstr /ixg:%search% %dir_out% >> %out%
```

Comment: probably, `dir /s /b`

Comment: That really help.  I found the other issue, too.  When I am creating the in.txt file, whitespace is added after both entries, so no results were returned.

sigh

Thanks for your help

Comment: `Dir c:\windows\*.exe c:\windows\*.bat /s /b`

Comment: You are outputting a space with your code. That was explained to you in your very first question on StackOverFlow.

Comment: outputting all files on the drive with `dir /s /b` and filter later is just so inefficient. Why waste your time printing millions or billions of files then reading that huge file again to filter? There are already a lot of questions about finding file in batch, just use it and don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate all files in a directory using a 'for' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138497/iterate-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-for-loop)

Comment: `Where /R "C:\" notepad.exe download.bat>"C:\Match_Output.txt"` or for paths only from a `for` loop, `For /F "Delims=" %A In ('Where /R "C:\" notepad.exe download.bat') Do @Echo %~dpA>>"C:\Match_Output.txt"`, _(double up the **`%`** characters from a batch file)_.