# Windows bat script for loop if substring in string

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to modify the for loop on a list of files [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138497/iterate-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-for-loop), adding to it, a check if a sub-string exists in the file name:

`for /r %%i in (*) do echo %%i`

How can I modify the above windows bat script to check if a sub-string exists in a file name or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this:

```
for /r %i in (*sub_string*) do echo %i
```

Or if you are using a batch file:

```
for /r %%i in (*sub_string*) do echo %%i
```

Here is my directory structure:

[image]

Output of running the following command:

```
for /r %i in (*test*) do echo %i
```

Is as follows:

```
C:\Users\czimmerman\Development\CMDTest>for /r %i in (*test*) do echo %i

C:\Users\czimmerman\Development\CMDTest>echo C:\Users\czimmerman\Development\CMD
Test\test1.txt
C:\Users\czimmerman\Development\CMDTest\test1.txt

C:\Users\czimmerman\Development\CMDTest>echo C:\Users\czimmerman\Development\CMD
Test\test2.txt
C:\Users\czimmerman\Development\CMDTest\test2.txt

C:\Users\czimmerman\Development\CMDTest>
```

Notice there is no `notthisone.txt` listed.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use string substitution (check [[SS64]: Variable Edit/Replace](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) or [[SO]: Batch file: Find if substring is in string (not in a file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005951/batch-file-find-if-substring-is-in-string-not-in-a-file) for more details). 
Because it happens in a *for* loop, *Delayed Expansion* ([[SS64]: EnableDelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)) must be taken into account.

For example, the following code filters file names that contain "*text*" and discards the rest (each found file name is printed at the beginning).

*script00.bat*:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /r %%f in (*) do (
    echo Found: %%f
    set __CURRENT_FILE=%%f
    if not "!__CURRENT_FILE:text=!" == "!__CURRENT_FILE!" (
        echo Filtered: !__CURRENT_FILE!
    )
)

echo Done.
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> echo Done.
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049137405]> dir /b
> code00.py
> other text.txt
> script00.bat
> text.txt
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049137405]> .\script00.bat
> Found: e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049137405\code00.py
> Found: e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049137405\other text.txt
> Filtered e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049137405\other text.txt
> Found: e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049137405\script00.bat
> Found: e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049137405\text.txt
> Filtered e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049137405\text.txt
> Done.
> ```