# Looping over directories in Windows XP command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

I have the following command which will loop over all the subdirectories in a specific location and output the full path:

```
for /d %i in ("E:\Test\*") do echo %i
```

Will give me:

```
E:\Test\One
E:\Test\Two
```

But how do I get both the full path, and just the directory name, so the do command might be something like:

```
echo %i - %j
```

And the output might be something like:

```
E:\Test\One - One
E:\Test\Two - Two
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following command syntax can be used to return the full path or directory name only:

```
%~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
%~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
```

Using your example, the following command will list directories in the format that you specified:

```
for /d %i in ("E:\Test*") do echo %~fi - %~ni
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "%~ni". This is an enhanced substitution that will return the file name of a path (or, more accurately, the last part, which is the directory name in your case):

```
for /d %i in ("E:\Test\*") do echo %i - %~ni
```

See also this question: [What does %~d0 mean in a Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112055/what-does-d0-mean-in-a-windows-batch-file)