# How do I know the default batch file directory?

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, batch-file, dos

I'm creating a batch file for SharePoint deployment. The batch will do solutions installation and configuration, create a web application and restore the **`.dat`** file on the created web application.

Instead of hard code the solutions path and **`.dat`** I want batch to know it is on the **`root`**. So, if I move this folder somewhere else I won't need to update the paths.

> **Is there any keyword of batch command which can tell where I stand
>   (batch file directory)?**

The batch script sample:

```
@SET STSADM="c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\12\bin\stsadm"

Echo copy solution files ...
%STSADM% -o addsolution -filename SmilingGoat.SharePoint.WebParts.Rss.wsp
%STSADM% -o deploysolution -name SmilingGoat.SharePoint.WebParts.Rss.wsp -immediate -allowgacdeployment -allcontenturls

%STSADM% -o addsolution -filename ReturnOfSmartPartv1_3.wsp
%STSADM% -o deploysolution -name ReturnOfSmartPartv1_3.wsp -immediate -allowgacdeployment -allcontenturls

Echo creating Learning Pitch application ... 
%STSADM% -o unextendvs -url http://server:70

%STSADM% -o restore -url http://server:70 -filename 2010.02.03.dat -overwrite

IISRESET

PAUSE
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, `%~p0` is what you are looking for.

For instance, if you create a file containing

```
echo %~p0
pause
```

and run it from `c:\temp` it will output "c:\temp".

EDIT: Actually [this answer in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112055/what-does-d0-mean-in-a-windows-batch-file/112135#112135) explains the idea.

Comment: But I have no idea, *why* it is named like this. I've used it since I found it in some example script, but the semantics behind the variable name is unclear to me.

Comment: thanks! i'll check it out. do you have any idea how to show preloader text like "..." and make it animated.

Comment: If the server where you are installing the package, has PowerShell installed, you can create a `.ps1` script instead of `.bat`. Then you can use "progress indicator" - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.03.powershell.aspx?pr=blog