# What does %~dp0 mean, and how does it work?

Tags: batch-file

I find `%~dp0` very useful, and I use it a lot to make my batch files more portable.

But the label itself seems very cryptic to me... What is the `~` doing? Does `dp` mean drive and path? Does the `0` refer to `%0`, the path to the batch file that includes the file name?

Or it is just a weird label?

I'd also like to know if it is a documented feature, or something prone to be deprecated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does %~d0 mean in a Windows batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112055/what-does-d0-mean-in-a-windows-batch-file)

Comment: You are right, Hellen.  That question didn't show up when I searched for %~dp0.  Maybe because it has %~d0 on it's title instead of %~dp0.

Comment: **SymbolHound** is great for conducting searches on other than alphanumeric characters. For instance, [search for `%~dp0`](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%25~dp0). Usually I find that the top hits refer to content on SO.

Comment: SymbolHound did not work for me with the search http://symbolhound.com/?q=%25~dp0. However this worked: https://www.google.com/search?q=%25~dp0 - just sayin'...

Comment: SymbolHound 2019: Does not work and uMatrix indicates that it connects to third party sites like blockchain.info and paypalobjects.com.

Comment: @Helen I love that that answer, which is older, [has a comment linking back to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112055/what-does-d0-mean-in-a-windows-batch-file#comment117287253_112055). ♾

Answer (score 958, accepted):

Calling

```
for /?
```

in the command-line gives help about this syntax (which can be used outside FOR, too, this is just the place where help can be found).

> In addition, substitution of FOR
>   variable references has been enhanced.
>   You can now use the following optional
>   syntax:
>
> ```
> %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
> %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
> %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
> %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
> %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
> %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
> %~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
> %~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
> %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
> %~zI        - expands %I to size of file
> %~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
>                environment variable and expands %I to the
>                fully qualified name of the first one found.
>                If the environment variable name is not
>                defined or the file is not found by the
>                search, then this modifier expands to the
>                empty string
> ```
>
> The modifiers can be combined to get
>   compound results:
>
> ```
> %~dpI       - expands %I to a drive letter and path only
> %~nxI       - expands %I to a file name and extension only
> %~fsI       - expands %I to a full path name with short names only
> %~dp$PATH:I - searches the directories listed in the PATH
>                environment variable for %I and expands to the
>                drive letter and path of the first one found.
> %~ftzaI     - expands %I to a DIR like output line
> ```
>
> In the above examples %I and PATH can
>   be replaced by other valid values. 
>   The %~ syntax is terminated by a valid
>   FOR variable name. Picking upper case
>   variable names like %I makes it more
>   readable and avoids confusion with the
>   modifiers, which are not case
>   sensitive.

There are different letters you can use like `f` for "full path name", `d` for drive letter, `p` for path, and they can be combined. `%~` is the beginning for each of those sequences and a number `I` denotes it works on the parameter `%I` (where `%0` is the complete name of the batch file, just like you assumed).

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but I get "The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter substitution is invalid. For valid formats type CALL /? or FOR /?. The syntax of the command is incorrect." when using `I`. I have to use `0` instead of `I`. I don't know if I've missed something or whatever, but just letting people know.

Comment: @BenHooper, `I` is a placeholder for the variable index. `0` = the calling file, `1` = argument #1, `2` = argument #2, etc...

Comment: This answer is good. And exhaustive. For a bit more brevity, I like the answer to this near-duplicate-question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112055/what-does-d0-mean-in-a-windows-batch-file

Comment: This answer is a little confusing because these substitutions can be used outside of FOR.

Comment: Note that if you run a batch file directly from C# using Process.Start, that batch file will expand `%~dp0` as the working directory of the C# program and NOT the location of the batch file. If you use Process.Start to run `cmd.exe` which in turn runs the batch file (e.g. using arguments `/C foo.bat`) then all is well. I suspect this is to do with how and where PATH is expanded. You can set the WorkingDirectory of the Process to fix this problem.

Answer (score 492):

(First, I'd like to recommend this useful reference site for batch:
http://ss64.com/nt/)

Then just another useful explanation: http://htipe.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/the-dp0-variable/

> ## The %~dp0 Variable
>
> The `%~dp0` (that’s a zero) variable when referenced within a Windows
> batch file will expand to the **d**rive letter and **p**ath of that batch
> file.
>
> The variables `%0-%9` refer to the command line parameters of the batch
> file. `%1-%9` refer to command line arguments after the batch file name.
> `%0` refers to the batch file itself.
>
> If you follow the percent character (`%`) with a tilde character (`~`),
> you can insert a modifier(s) before the parameter number to alter the
> way the variable is expanded. The `d` modifier expands to the drive
> letter and the `p` modifier expands to the path of the parameter.
>
> Example:  Let’s say you have a directory on `C:` called `bat_files`, and
> in that directory is a file called `example.bat`. In this case, `%~dp0`
> (combining the `d` and `p` modifiers) will expand to `C:\bat_files\`.
>
> Check out [this Microsoft article](https://web.archive.org/web/20180120021145/https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true) for a full explanation.
>
> Also, check out [this forum thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20160416192303/http://www.911cd.net/forums//index.php?showtopic=3730).

And a more clear reference from [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php):

- `%CmdCmdLine%`    will return the entire command line as passed to CMD.EXE
- `%*`  will return the remainder of the command line starting at the first command line argument (in Windows NT 4, %* also includes all leading spaces)
- `%~dn`    will return the drive letter of %n (n can range from 0 to 9) if %n is a valid path or file name (no UNC)
- `%~pn`    will return the directory of %n if %n is a valid path or file name (no UNC)
- `%~nn`    will return the file name only of %n if %n is a valid file name
- `%~xn`    will return the file extension only of %n if %n is a valid file name
- `%~fn`    will return the fully qualified path of %n if %n is a valid file name or directory

### ADD 1

Just found some good reference for the *mysterious* `~` tilde operator.

The `%~` string is called [percent tilde](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting#Percent_tilde) operator. You can find it in situations like: `%~0`.

The `:~` string is called [colon tilde](http://windowsjoe.blogspot.com/2008/11/mastering-windows-batch-files.html) operator. You can find it like `%SOME_VAR:~0,-1%`.

### ADD 2 - 1:12 PM 7/6/2018

`%1-%9` refer to the command line args. If they are **not** valid path values, `%~dp1` - `%~dp9` will all expand to the same value as `%~dp0`. But if they **are** valid path values, they will expand to **their own** driver/path value.

For example:
(batch.bat)

```
@echo off
@echo ~dp0= %~dp0
@echo ~dp1= %~dp1
@echo ~dp2= %~dp2
@echo on
```

Run 1:

```
D:\Workbench>batch arg1 arg2

~dp0= D:\Workbench\
~dp1= D:\Workbench\
~dp2= D:\Workbench\
```

Run 2:

```
D:\Workbench>batch c:\123\a.exe e:\abc\b.exe

~dp0= D:\Workbench\
~dp1= c:\123\
~dp2= e:\abc\
```

Comment: Also curious about this concept and found the good clarification here. Thanks Mingge. ^_^

Comment: for me it expands to c:\bat_files\ (with trailing path seperator)

Comment: The links to the Microsoft article and the forum thread do not work anymore :(

Comment: If you give it relative paths, they will be expanded as relative paths, which means relative to your current directory... which, in your test, happens to be the same directory as `%~dp0`. `%~dp1` doesn't magically become `%~dp0` just because the file `arg1` doesn't exist; you might want your batch file to create it!

Answer (score 176):

The variable `%0` in a batch script is set to the name of the executing batch file.

The `~dp` special syntax between the `%` and the `0` basically says to expand the variable `%0` to show the drive letter and path, which gives you the current directory containing the batch file!

Help = [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180120021145/https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: @Andy, Is there any way to test `%0` directly in the cmd without saving a .bat file to local harddrive?

Comment: Link is broken, and I am not able to find the correct link. A pending edit still has the broken link.

Answer (score 61):

%~dp0 expands to current directory path of the running batch file.

To get clear understanding, let's create a batch file in a directory.

> C:\script\test.bat

with contents:

```
@echo off
echo %~dp0
```

When you run it from command prompt, you will see this result:

> C:\script\

Answer (score 44):

Another tip that would help a lot is that to set the current directory to a **different drive** one would have to use **`%~d0`** first, then **`cd %~dp0`**. This will change the directory to the batch file's drive, then change to its folder.

Alternatively, for #oneLinerLovers, as @Omni pointed out in the comments **`cd /d %~dp0`** will change both the drive and directory :)

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: `cd` has a built in parameter that will switch both the drive and the folder: `cd /d %~dp0`

Comment: You are right and the `/d` argument is helpful, but it deserves to be posted as a **candidate alternative answer** and **not a comment** to this one. _Thank you_ for pointing this out though, I didn't know about it :)

Comment: you could also use ''pushd %~dp0'' to switch drive and folder

Answer (score 27):

Great example from Strawberry Perl's portable shell launcher:

```
set drive=%~dp0
set drivep=%drive%
if #%drive:~-1%# == #\# set drivep=%drive:~0,-1%

set PATH=%drivep%\perl\site\bin;%drivep%\perl\bin;%drivep%\c\bin;%PATH%
```

not sure what the negative 1's doing there myself, but it works a treat!

Comment: +1 very useful. The if statement checks if a backslash is present and removes the backslash if necessary. The negative 1 in the condition extracts the last character, and the expression in the set statement takes the path string minus the last character (which is the backslash).

Comment: negative 1 is minus the last character. Read [variable substring](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

Answer (score 13):

An example would be nice - here's a trivial one

```
for %I in (*.*) do @echo %~xI
```

it lists only the EXTENSIONS of each file in current folder

for more useful variable combinations (also listed in previous response) from the CMD prompt execute:  `HELP FOR`
which contains this snippet

The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:

```
%~dpI       - expands %I to a drive letter and path only
%~nxI       - expands %I to a file name and extension only
%~fsI       - expands %I to a full path name with short names only
%~dp$PATH:I - searches the directories listed in the PATH
               environment variable for %I and expands to the
               drive letter and path of the first one found.
%~ftzaI     - expands %I to a DIR like output line
```

Comment: i got "~xI was unexpected at this time." trying out the example - is it because i am using Win 7?

Comment: This is good information, but it fails to address the original post.

Comment: @chapter3  **`~xI`** or **`~xl`** or **L** / Low = **`l`** or  **I** / Low = **`i`** ? 