# Scrapy.bat explanation

Tags: python, batch-file, scrapy

In the Python Scrapy framework there is a scrapy.bat file:

```
@echo off

setlocal

"%~dp0..\python" "%~dp0scrapy" %*
endlocal
```

Could someone explain what this does? Especially this line `"%~dp0..\python" "%~dp0scrapy" %*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This  is batch syntax. `%0` is the first argument which is the path name of the current batch file. ~dp is for path manipulation and means drive and path. In effect, it launches python from a folder up(`%~dp0..`) and load scrapy module. The `%*` means pass other arguments passed to the batch to the script.

Comment: i tried simple example - echo %~dp0 it works! But when i use 1 -  echo %~dp1 (or any other digit) it doesnt work! why??

Comment: How do you call your batch ? If you don't pass argument, you can echo them. Moreover if the first argument is not a pathname, you can't use path expansion with it.

Comment: i just double click bat file which contains: echo %~dp0  (and pause) bat file is in Desktop folder.

Comment: That's why you can't print %~dp1, %0 is implicit when you execute the batch file but if you double click on it, you're not passing arguments yourself so there's nothing to print other than %0.

Comment: Thanks!! is there a complete guide or reference to batch programming?? Do you know a link??

Comment: Sure google batch programming and you should get tons of reference.

Answer (score 2):

You want to know primarily what `%~dp0` means; for that, try taking a look at [What does %~dp0 mean, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work) (Remember to search for such things. Search is good.)

Once you understand what `%~dp0` means, the rest is easy, but you can get it spelled out by turning a command into an `echo` statement—`echo "%~dp0..\python" "%~dp0scrapy" %*`. This is a handy technique in batch file comprehension; poor man's variable inspection.

As for `setlocal` and `endlocal`, try (a) `help` and (b) the power of search.