# Unable to access jarfile lib\archquery.jar

Tags: android, sdk, installation

*Problem:*

- Unable to open SDK Manager (Flashes only for a second)
- No build path target in Eclipse

---

*Paths:*

```
Android SDK: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk
JDK used for android: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04 (There are other JDKs also in dir Java)
```

---

*Environment Variables:*

```
ANDROID_SDK_HOME: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.6.0;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7;
System Path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.5.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\
```

---

*Errors:*

```
SDK Manager on cmd
Failed to execute tools\android.bat. 
The system cannot find the file specified

Android.bat on cmd
Unable to access jar file lib\archquery.jar
Invalid path

find_java on cmd
nothing returned
```

Answer (score 25):

I had a similar issue - I had to edit the android.bat ( and traceview.bat when I needed it)

in android.bat look for

```
for /f %%a in ('%java_exe% -jar %frameworkdir%archquery.jar') do set swt_path=%frameworkdir%%%a
```

replace with

```
set swt_path=lib\x86
```

Comment: OH GOD THANK YOU... been trying to get the android SDK to run for over an hour...

Answer (score 8):

YMMV, but **in addition** to editing android.bat, as described in the previous answer, I still couldn't get the SDK Manager to run on Windows 8 64-bit, until I first:

- uninstalled ALL versions of Java
- **rebooted***
- installed ONLY the X86 JDK (including the Public JRE option in the installer)

I had tried all of these things and more previously *WITHOUT rebooting, and this was the only way I ever got the SDK Manager to run.  Hopefully this info saves you from some of the utter frustration and wasted time I experienced.  What a pain in the ass just to get the tools running out of the box.  Awful experience.

I would have replied as a comment to the previous answer, but apparently I don't have enough rep to do that:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25725/how-do-you-comment-on-a-specific-answer

**EDIT: More complete answer below. (I don't think rebooting had anything to do with it.)**

There appear to be several ways to launch the SDK Manager:

1. `SDK Manager.exe` in the root of the Android SDK.
2. `SDK Manager.exe` in `sdk\tools\lib` of the Android SDK.
3. `Window -> Android SDK Manager` menu in Eclipse
4. `android.bat` in `sdk\tools` of the Android SDK.

In my case, it looks like `android.bat` fails on the line:

```
for /f %%a in ('%java_exe% -jar lib\archquery.jar') do set swt_path=lib\%%a
```

As far as what that line is doing... if I manually run: `"[path_to_java]java" -jar lib\archquery.jar`

It successfully returns: `x86_64`

But when the batch file runs that same command, I don't know why but it fails with the error message:

```
Unable to access jarfile lib\archquery.jar
```

So the variable `swt_path` gets set to an empty string.  Everything breaks down from there.

The batch file sets the correct value for the variable `java_exe`.  Others have commonly reported this as a problem, but those workarounds weren't relevant in my case.

People have recommended commenting out the problem line by adding REM to the beginning of it, and adding a line to manually set the `swt_path` variable, which is a valid workaround:

```
REM for /f %%a in ('%java_exe% -jar lib\archquery.jar') do set swt_path=lib\%%a
set swt_path=lib\x86
```

**BUT**, the critical issue in my case is that it's choosing to load a jar file from either the `lib\x86` or the `lib\x86_64` folder here.  At some point, things were getting confused between the BAT file error, a 32-bit JDK, and a 64-bit Android SDK.

**SO**, the workaround in my case was to:

1. Uninstall ALL versions of Java
2. Install the JDK

   - You can either use the 32-bit Android SDK and install the 32-bit JDK
   - Or use the 64-bit Android SDK and install the 64-bit JDK
   - But the "bitness" of the JDK should match the Android SDK.  It appears that either of the 32-bit or the 64-bit will work on a 64-bit computer, AS LONG AS the JDK bitness matches the Android SDK bitness.
3. Edit "android.bat"

   - If using the 32-bit Android SDK/JDK, use `lib\x86`:

     ```
     REM for /f %%a in ('%java_exe% -jar lib\archquery.jar') do set swt_path=lib\%%a
     set swt_path=lib\x86
     ```
   - If using the 64-bit Android SDK/JDK, use `lib\x86_64`:

     ```
     REM for /f %%a in ('%java_exe% -jar lib\archquery.jar') do set swt_path=lib\%%a
     set swt_path=lib\x86_64
     ```

After doing this, I can successfully run the SDK Manager by running `android.bat`, or from the Eclipse menu (but still not by running either of the `SDK Manager.exe` files directly).

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 7, at least, a batch 'FOR' loop, when executing a command for the list, does not use the current working directory, but the root.  In this case, the command is '%java_exe% -jar lib\archquery.jar'.  However, it's effectively being run from the root, e.g. 'C:\'.  You can see this for your self with this simple test from the command line:

```
for /f %a in ('CD') do echo %a
```

So the command to run archquery is looking for the jar relative to the root directory, not your ADT directory, and thus can't be found.

Comment: I fixed my android.bar to use the full path to archquery, leveraging the %work_dir% variable set up earlier in the batch file:

for /f %%a in ('%java_exe% -jar %work_dir%\lib\archquery.jar') do set swt_path=lib\%%a

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue and this is how it is solved.

1. Open `android.bat` file from `\android-sdk-windows\tools` in an editor.
2. Find the line

   ```
   for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"%java_exe%" -jar lib\archquery.jar') do set swt_path=lib\%%a
   ```

   and add `rem` in front of this line.
3. In the next line add `set swt_path=lib\x86` (if you are using a 32-bit system) or `set swt_path=lib\x86_64` (if you are using a 64-bit system).
4. Save the file. Close the cmd if you have one open. Navigate to `android-sdk-windows\tools\` and run android. This should open SDK manager. But be sure to have `JAVA_HOME` defined in your environment variables and should point to JDK home.

Answer (score 1):

This change to android.bat (below) fixed the problem for me. I can launch the SDK manager from Eclipse now too.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"%java_exe%" -jar %~dp0\lib\archquery.jar') do set swt_path=lib\%%a
```

See [What does %~dp0 mean, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that by replacing:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"%java_exe%" -jar lib\archquery.jar') do set swt_path=lib\%%a
```

with

```
REM for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"%java_exe%" -jar lib\archquery.jar') do set swt_path=lib\%%a
set swt_path="lib\x86_64"
```

Note that i used `"` for the `swt_path` variable.

Hope that could help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an environmental variable called "ANDROID_SWT" pointing to the directory that holds swt.jar got this to work for me. Seems like a better option then modifying the script.