# Installing Windows Service with batch file?

Tags: windows-services, batch-file, installutil

I have the following in a bat file :

```
@ECHO OFF

REM The following directory is for .NET 4.0
set DOTNETFX2=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
set PATH=%PATH%;%DOTNETFX2%

echo Installing IEPPAMS Win Service...
echo ---------------------------------------------------
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil My.WindowsService.exe
echo ---------------------------------------------------
pause
echo Done.
```

The problem is that it even if the bat file is located in the same folder as the My.WindowsService.exe it will try to look for it in C:\Windows\System32.....

How do I solve this?

Comment: Just guessing, but what about .\My.WindowsService.exe?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is how it is solved :

```
@ECHO OFF

REM The following directory is for .NET 4.0
set DOTNETFX2=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
set PATH=%PATH%;%DOTNETFX2%

echo Installing IEPPAMS Win Service...
echo ---------------------------------------------------
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil "%~dp0My.WindowsService.exe"
echo ---------------------------------------------------
pause
echo Done.
```

Comment: "%~dp0" - The %~dp0 (that’s a zero) variable when referenced within a Windows batch file will expand to the drive letter and path of that batch file.

The variables %0-%9 refer to the command line parameters of the batch file. %1-%9 refer to command line arguments after the batch file name. %0 refers to the batch file itself. [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10290765/3378621)

Comment: Why bother `set DOTNETFX2` and `set PATH` when you've hardcoded the path to InstallUtil as `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ ` ?

Answer (score 6):

According to several articles I've found, passing an absolute path to your service is what you want. For example:

```
{...Path_To_.NET_Framework...}\InstallUtil C:\MyFolder\My.WindowsService.exe
```

You can grab your current directory with something like this in your batch file, if you want a dynamically generated path:

```
set CURDIR=%CD%
{...Path_To_.NET_Framework...}\InstallUtil %CURDIR%\My.WindowsService.exe
```

References:

- [How to Install Windows Service using command prompt](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/d8f300e3-6c09-424f-829e-c5fda34c1bc7/)
- [Install Windows Service](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/52471/Install-Windows-Service)

Answer (score 2):

It is too old but was useful for me... I made some changes.

My service starts manually so, in the batch I included the start command and then open the console for checking the Installed Service.

```
@ECHO OFF

REM The following directory is for .NET 4.0
set DOTNETFX2=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
set PATH=%PATH%;%DOTNETFX2%

echo Installing MyService Win Service...
echo ---------------------------------------------------
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil /i "%~dp0MyService.exe"
net start MyService
services.msc
echo ---------------------------------------------------
pause
echo Done.
```

Answer (score 1):

### Examples of install and uninstall

```
@ECHO OFF

REM The following directory is for .NET 4.0
set DOTNETFX2=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
set PATH=%PATH%;%DOTNETFX2%

echo Instalar Servicio......
echo ---------------------------------------------------
InstallUtil /i "%~dp0WindowsService1.exe"
echo ---------------------------------------------------
pause
echo Done.



@ECHO OFF

REM The following directory is for .NET 4.0
set DOTNETFX2=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
set PATH=%PATH%;%DOTNETFX2%

echo Desintalar Servicio...
echo ---------------------------------------------------
InstallUtil /u "%~dp0WindowsService1.exe"
echo ---------------------------------------------------
pause
echo Done.
```