# What does %~dp0 mean

Tags: batch-file, modifiers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does %~dp0 mean, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work)

i had to modify a bat file in my work a few days ago.
when i read the file,i found i didn't know what the string "%~dp0" means.
i got the explanation of it on the microsoft web site.
it said "%~dp0   Expands %0 to a drive letter and path."
my question is what dose expand mean?
why the result is driver letter + path,not driver letter + path + the name of bat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Expands means that the identifier is replaced with its value.
2. `dp` means drive letter and path.  `%0` alone would include the filename.