# fail install Node.js version management

Tags: node.js

I install node.js windows.today I want install Node.js version management.I use "$ npm install -g n"./%AppData%/Roaming/npm has n module.But when I usage command "n",it show--

> ' sh is not a internal external command'

the code in n.cmd is follow:

`:: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\sh.exe" (
  "%~dp0\sh.exe"  "%~dp0\node_modules\n\bin\n" %*
) ELSE (
  sh  "%~dp0\node_modules\n\bin\n" %*
)`

what sh.exe it is?
I install UnxUtils,it has a sh.exe.I put it path in environment path,it fail too:the cmd
window became very small, I can't seen any infomation on it,and it not work fine!

Comment: %~dp0 expands %0 to [drive letter and path.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work