# Using drag and drop from another directory onto a batch file does not work

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a folder structure that looks like this:

```
project
    bin
        my_program.exe
        misc_stuff.exe
    DROP_OVER_ME.bat
    input_file.txt
```

Basically, I want to be able to drag and drop the input file on top of the `DROP_OVER_ME.bat` batch file and have it pass on the path of the input file to the exe.

This is what my batch file looks like:

```
@echo off
start bin/my_program.exe %1
exit
```

When I drag and drop `input_file.txt` over the batch file, everything works fine -- `my_program.exe` successfully receives the path of the input file and runs.

However, when `input_file.txt` is located outside the project folder, dragging and dropping it makes the batch file throw up a popup message saying

> Windows cannot find 'bin/my_program.exe'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.

How can I fix my batch file so I can drag and drop files from any arbitrary location inside my filesystem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like the batch script is basing the current working directory as the directory you're dragging *from*, and not the directory containing the script.  (You can test this by adding an `echo %cd% && pause` to your script if you wish.)  Try modifying your script as follows to remove any ambiguity about file paths:

```
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"
start "" "bin\my_program.exe" "%~f1"
exit /b
```

Comment: I had to remove the quotes around 'bin\my_program.exe' to make it work (it kept opening the text file in notepad), but apart from that, it worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Oh, yeah, because the first parameter expected by `start` is the title of the window.  I should've added empty quotes before the `bin\my_program.exe` part.  I'll fix it above.  Sorry about that.

Comment: cd /d "%~dp0" just fixed a similar problem for me - thanks!

Comment: For more info on all the options like dp0, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work