# Running batch file from USB drive when drive letter changes

Tags: batch-file

So, I have made a batch script and it executes multiple portable programs (e.g., prog1.exe, prog2.exe, etc). The problem is whenever I connect the USB drive to another computer, the drive letters change, giving me errors when running my .bat file. Please help me find a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Is the batch file hosted on the USB, or is the batch file local and the USB holds another resource that you're trying to access?

Comment: If the batch is hosted on the USB (as JohnLBevan has asked), forget this question (and use %~d0). Otherwise: Is fixing the drive letter on the computers an option?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`%~d0` gives you the current drive letter (including the colon).  If the batch file's contained on the USB drive, you can use that.

So, for instance, instead of

```
E:\PortablePrograms\ProgramName.exe
```

you would write

```
%~d0\PortablePrograms\ProgramName.exe
```

... or you could do something like this

```
::change directory to the script's directory's drive
pushd %~d0
::navigate from the drive to the relevant path(s)
cd PortablePrograms
::execute any programs
ProgramName.exe
SecondProgramName.exe
::just because I like to pair my pushes with pops; not required
popd
```

Comment: No worries - thanks also to @AndriyM for contributing the expanded part of the answer.

Comment: ps. Anyone interested in `%~d0` may also be interested in these similar variables: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5034119/361842

Answer (score 2):

This is how I get the last removable drive in a listing.

```
    @echo off

    :: Drivetypes
    ::  0=Unknown
    ::  1=No Root Directory
    ::  2=Removable(USB,Firewire)
    ::  3=Local Disk (Internal Hard Drive)
    ::  4=Network Drive(\\Server\share\)
    ::  5=Compact Disk (CD DVD)
    ::  6=Ram Disk
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%d in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=2" 
    get name /format:value') do set driveletter= %%d
    echo %driveletter%
    pause
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use command line argument `%1`, `%2` as input path, and modify your bat file accordingly.