# How can I use a batch file to write to a text file?

Tags: file, batch-file, text

I need to make a script that can write one line of text to a text file in the same directory as the batch file.

Comment: Quick and easy one-liner.

`echo "some text here" >> myfile.txt`

Answer (score 392, accepted):

You can use [`echo`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772462%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), and redirect the output to a text file (see notes below):

```
rem Saved in D:\Temp\WriteText.bat
@echo off
echo This is a test> test.txt
echo 123>> test.txt
echo 245.67>> test.txt
```

Output:

```
D:\Temp>WriteText

D:\Temp>type test.txt
This is a test
123
245.67

D:\Temp>
```

Notes:

- `@echo off` turns off printing of each command to the console
- `@` at the beginning of the remaining lines stops printing of the `echo` command itself, but does not suppress `echo` output. (It allows the rest of the line after `@echo` to display.
- Unless you give it a specific path name, redirection with `>` or `>>` will write to the current directory (the directory the code is being run in).
- The `@echo This is a test > test.txt` uses one `>` to overwrite any file that already exists with new content.
- The remaining `@echo` statements use two `>>` characters to append to the text file (add to), instead of overwriting it.
- The `type test.txt` simply types the file output to the command window.

Answer (score 155):

It's easier to use only one code block, then you only need one redirection.

```
(
  echo Line1
  echo Line2
  ...
  echo Last Line
) > filename.txt
```

Comment: OMG so simple & it makes it half-way human which is impressive since scripting is like the intro to the jibberish world of programming

Comment: This didn't work for me, but a variation with the redirection in front of the block `    > filename.txt ( ` did work.

Comment: @willw I suppose, there is an additional closing parenthesis somewhere in your code block.Else it must work, regardless if you put the redirection in front or after the block

Comment: @jeb Possibly - I no longer have my original test file, so can't be sure. Certainly I have subsequently had to escape closing ) characters as ^), which would tend to support your hypothesis. Still, at least our discussion alerts others to a possible trap.

Comment: Change `...` to `echo ...` to make it executable. I don't understand why it doesn't append to an existing file.

Comment: @flywire Appending requires `>> filename.txt`, for creating a new file use `> filename.txt`

Comment: Of course, thanks.

Comment: Don't work when copy/paste in cmd.

Comment: @vernou You have to remove the dots, they are only placeholders

Comment: @jeb Indeed... It's work. Thank.

Answer (score 32):

`echo "blahblah"> txt.txt` will erase the txt and put blahblah in it's place

`echo "blahblah">> txt.txt` will write blahblah on a new line in the txt

I think that both will create a new txt if none exists (I know that the first one does)

Where "`txt.txt`" is written above, a file path can be inserted if wanted. e.g. `C:\Users\<username>\desktop`, which will put it on their desktop.

Comment: yes, it's true for both. Sadly your answer doesn't add additional information to the existing answers.(mentioning `'%~dp0` would...)

Comment: to write to a txt in the same folder?

Comment: to write into the folder, [where the batchfile resides](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10290765/2152082) (independent of any `cd` or `pushd` commands)

Answer (score 16):

```
    @echo off

    (echo this is in the first line) > xy.txt
    (echo this is in the second line) >> xy.txt

    exit
```

The two `>>` means that the second line will be appended to the file (i.e. second line will start after the last line of xy.txt).

this is how the `xy.txt` looks like:

```
this is in the first line
this is in the second line
```

Answer (score 5):

@echo off
Title Writing using Batch Files
color 0a

echo Example Text > Filename.txt
echo Additional Text >> Filename.txt

```html
@ECHO OFF
Title Writing Using Batch Files
color 0a

echo Example Text > Filename.txt
echo Additional Text >> Filename.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

- You can use `copy con`  to write a long text
- Example:

  > C:\COPY CON [drive:][path][File name]
  >
  > .... Content
  >
  > F6
  >
  > 1 file(s) is copied

Comment: In a batch file, copy con prompts the user.

Comment: `copy con` is useless in a batch file. It also requires user input, whether at the terminal prompt or in a batch file, so it does not do anything the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

echo Type your text here.

:top

set /p boompanes=

pause

echo %boompanes%> practice.txt
```

hope this helps. you should change the string names(IDK what its called) and the file name