# How can I use a batch file to write to a cmd file?

Tags: batch-file, process, cmd

i want to write some codes in cmd by batch file

{CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "%comspec% /c start /wait cmd.exe", 0, True }

this code opens cmd.exe ..

How can I edit this file with my own dos commands ?
i dont want use it in txt file?
my question is to write some command lines to cmd.exe
not to txt file by "echo > & echo >> " 
i need to  open cmd and start write instructions with a batch file
and how i get some information from the cmd and place it in another script to use it later

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use a batch file to write to a text file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19878136/how-can-i-use-a-batch-file-to-write-to-a-text-file)

Comment: i dont want use it in txt file?
my question is to write some command lines to cmd.exe

i.e open cmd and start write instructions

Comment: A ..cmd file is a .txt file with a different extension. All content in a .cmd file is plain text. So you write text to the .cmd file, just as you would write text to a .txt file. It's the same thing.

Comment: { START cmd.exe /k "netsh wlan show profiles" } this is code 
if i use < such as text file it will be transfer the instruction to  the txt file and i didn't want that ?

Answer (score 0):

`Wscript.shell.run` uses shell32 to start files. You ask it to specifically start cmd.exe (`%comspec%`), which you ask that cmd.exe to ask shell32 (the `start` command) to start cmd.exe. Put the commands you want to run in a batch file (that's a text file).

```
Wscript.shell.run "c:\folder\batchfile.bat"
```

or if you prefer

```
Wscript.shell.run "cmd /c c:\folder\batchfile.bat"
```

or if only one command

```
Wscript.shell.run "cmd /k dir"
```

see

```
cmd /?
```

Comment: this run file only how to start write instructions to this file
"cmd instructions not txt file "

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to start cmd, then start write code which was saved in batch file

The code will be like this:

```
  {    START cmd.exe /k "netsh wlan show profiles"    }
```

This code will open cmd and show you the saved profiles