# Windows 8 Xcopy problems

Tags: batch-file, windows-8, syntax, cmd, windows-8.1

I need to create a (.bat) file to run off USB to copy files and folders from that drive to a specific folder on each computer. EG.

xcopy \copy*.* C:\Windows\inf\ /h /e /i /k /y

The above code used to work with Windows 7 but now no longer works due to the new admin restrictions on Windows 8. I have managed to get the admin right to run with the code below, which I found on this site.

```
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Automatically check & get admin rights
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 @echo off
 CLS 
 ECHO.
 ECHO =============================
 ECHO Running Admin shell
 ECHO =============================

 :checkPrivileges 
 NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
 if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges ) 

 :getPrivileges 
 if '%1'=='ELEV' (shift & goto gotPrivileges)  
 ECHO. 
 ECHO **************************************
 ECHO Invoking UAC for Privilege Escalation 
 ECHO **************************************

 setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
 set "batchPath=%~0"
 setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
 ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", "ELEV", "", "runas", 1 >>      "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
 "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
 exit /B 

 :gotPrivileges 
 ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 :START
 ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 setlocal & pushd .

 REM Run shell as admin 

 xcopy \copy\*.* C:\Windows\inf\ /h /e /i /k /y
 cmd /k
```

But now I keep getting `invalid directory` because of the varying location of the USB drive, which appears in some systems as (G:) others as (H:). Am I going down the correct path here and just have incorrect syntax or is it completely wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Just so you guys know, I'm copying driver folders with some hidden files and folders and all of the systems need to have the identical files on them.

Regards
Adam M

Comment: Aren't there so many better ways to do this kind of thing than walking around stuffing thumb drives in computers?

Comment: @AndrewBarber there sure are. But the question can surely be boiled down to a valid problem, regardless of intended use.

Comment: The question is probably getting downvotes, because you are not sufficiently describing your problem but effectively are dumping your code and asking us to tell you, where you went wrong. - Could you, instead, try to tell us, what you have tried to fix your problem and why or how it didn't work? Do you understand the code you found and used? What does it do? And so on...

Answer (score 0):

You need the ["%~dp0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work), it expands to G: or H: on the fly.

```
xcopy %~dp0copy\*.* C:\Windows\inf\ /h /e /i /k /y
```