# How to set up emacs with nuwen

Tags: batch-file, emacs, mingw

[nuwen](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) has the following bat file for setting up its environmental variables inside a command line shell:

```bsh
set X_DISTRO=nuwen
if exist "%~dp0git\cmd\git.exe" set PATH=%~dp0git\cmd;%PATH%
set PATH=%~dp0bin;%PATH%
set X_MEOW=%~dp0include;%~dp0include\freetype2
if defined C_INCLUDE_PATH (set C_INCLUDE_PATH=%X_MEOW%;%C_INCLUDE_PATH%) else (set C_INCLUDE_PATH=%X_MEOW%)
if defined CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH (set CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=%X_MEOW%;%CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH%) else (set CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=%X_MEOW%)
set X_MEOW=
```

I'm not well versed in batch, so how can I parse this and set it up in emacs? I've taken a look at [Exec Path](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ExecPath). In particular I would like to be able to run <kbd>M-x</kbd> compile, so I don't need to keep a command line window open.

Comment: This looks very painful. Developing C++ with Emacs on Windows.
C++ with Emacs on Linux is nice, so is C++ with Visual Studio on Windows, but something in between - I just don't see the point. Maybe you could try a VM with Linux instead of mingw?

Comment: @abo-abo It's the alternative to just using notepad++, honestly.

Comment: Couldn't you just look what is set in a command line shell and then set it in emacs via `(setenv "..." "...")` or even in window's setting of environment variables. It is not worth the effort to parse the batch file if the settings remain the same for successive calls of gcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%~dp0` here means full path to the executing script, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work). So, for example, if this script is placed inside the `C:\My` directory, `%~dp0git` will be equal to `C:\My\git`.

Other features used in the script are hopefully easier to interpret. `%X_MEOW%` means "take the `X_MEOW` variable value" and `if` semantics are similar to any other language.