# batch file will not run as administrator

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to run this code in a windows batch (.bat) file

```
@echo off

echo Adding New User - LogMeInRemoteUser
net user | find /i "LogMeInRemoteUser" || Net user LogMeInRemoteUser password /add /fullname:"LogMeInRemoteUser"

pause

echo Adding User to Administrators Group
NET LOCALGROUP Administrators "LogMeInRemoteUser" /ADD

pause

echo Creating Registry Keys to remove the new user from the login page
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList" /v "LogMeInRemoteUser" /t REG_DWORD /d 0

pause

echo Finished
```

if i run the file normally, i get an Access Denied error so I try to run as Administrator but the cmd windows opens and instantly closes, what have i done wrong?

Comment: Do the pause prompts appears?  if not, have you called the bat file `net` or `reg` or `find` ?  Try calling it `mybatch.bat` as a test.

Comment: The issue is related to incorrect handling special characters, see
https://superuser.com/questions/1503300/why-can-we-not-run-as-administrator-a-batch-file-with-in-the-path

Answer (score 2):

When you run as administrator the current directory is changed under you.  To prove that (and fix it) enter these 3 lines under your @echo off

```
echo(%cd%
pushd %~dp0
echo(%cd%
```

You can remove both of the echo( statements after you see what is happening.

Comment: the cmd window still just closes straight away

Comment: Try putting    NET USER /?  on the 2nd line and   PAUSE   on the 3rd line.

Comment: The current directory isn't important in the batch code above.

Comment: Related: [What does %~dp0 mean, and how does it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5034076/1497596)

Comment: %~dp0 provides the drive letter and path of the bat file. You can find a good explanation at http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html