# Nested FOR Loop in CMD

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, cmd, nested

The following works in Command Line but the second one fails in the Batch script.  By fails I mean that it exit the .Bat immediately.  Does not even stop at a PAUSE immediately following the `FOR /F` ...... executing line.

Console:

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1 delims="  %I IN ('Dir *.Properties /B') DO (If NOT EXIST ..\Working\%~nI_ru.properties copy %~nI.properties ..\New_Files\%~nI_ru.properties)
```

Batch file:

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1 delims=" %%I IN ('Dir *.Properties /B') DO (If NOT EXIST ..\Working\%%~nI_ru.properties copy %%~nI.properties ..\New_Files\%%~nI_ru.properties)
```

It is comparing two software version releases and selecting those 'new' property files available and copying them to a New_File directory with filename change.
ThisIsANewFile.properties is copied as ThisIsANewFile**_ru**.properties  i.e.  `_ru` appended to the FileName

Thanks to anyone who knows what I've done wrong,

Comment: Please surround your code with code-tags

Comment: Do your filenames contain spaces or `&` characters?  If so then the terms will need to be quoted.  Open a cmd window and launch the batch file.  You will see the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're script has a hard time locating the files that's it's trying to copy since the batch file usually starts in `C:\Windows\System32\`  try adding `cd /d %~dp0` before your `for /f` loop.  Like so:

```
cd /d %~dp0
FOR /F "TOKENS=1 delims=" %%I IN ('Dir *.Properties /B') DO (If NOT EXIST ..\Working\%%~nI_ru.properties copy %%~nI.properties ..\New_Files\%%~nI_ru.properties)
```

`%~dp0` is gives you the location where the batch file was called from.  See [%~dp0 SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work)

You can also use absolute paths. for example `Dir C:\MyApp\*.Properties /B`

Comment: A batch file only starts in `C:\Windows\System32` when it is run as admin.