# Batch file to print receipts

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to get a program that was left to me to work on another PC, it won't print.

The printer works fine but it won't print using a batch file. There's 2 batch files that I think I need to run, 1 is called "auto_net_use" which contains

```
Net Use LPT1: \\opr-02\EPSONTM- /PERSISTENT:YES
```

What does this do? is it the share path? is opr-02 the name of the PC?

Here's the batch file for printing a text file used by the program

```
@echo off
cd \
set pth=%~dp0
Print "%pth%balance_inquiry.txt"
pause
exit
```

What is "set pth=%dp0" ?

Answer (score 0):

`Net Use LPT1: \\opr-02\EPSONTM- /PERSISTENT:YES` is mapping a printer named `EPSONTM-` that's located on the `opr-02` system

`set pth=%~dp0` is the current directory where the script was called from. See More [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: how about LPT1? it's the port right? the printer is connected via usb. It was using a different port before and the batch file kept saying it can't find the printer, when I changed it to LPT1 it says it's printing the file but nothing happens, it eventually times out and the printer errors.