# Rename file, but 4 letters in

Tags: batch-file

I have this code:

`%a%` represents a folders name e.g. "TEST123"

```
for %%a in (*) do rename "%%a" "%%a-%a%"
```

The function above renames all the files in that folder by appending the file name with the folders name e.g.

From`Water.avi`
To`water.avi-TEST123`

This issue is that I want the ".avi" to be at the end.

Is there a way to get rename to rename but 4 letters in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, using the modifiers :

```
for %%a in (*) do rename "%%a" "%%~na-%a%%%~xa"
```

Comment: There is various delimiters you can use in a FOR loop. Check `FOR /?`. `%%~na` for just the name, `%%~xa` for the extension, etc...

Comment: Here is a full list of modifiers if don't have a console near by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work/5034119#5034119