# How to automatically mount virtual hard disk from anywhere?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have these 3 files in a folder and they are all located in `C:\Max`:

**attach.bat**:

```
@echo off
cd %~dp0
diskpart /s run.txt
```

**run.txt**:

```
select vdisk file="C:\Max\maximus.vhd" 
attach vdisk
```

**maximus.vhd**: a virtual hard disk drive which is mounted via the other 2 files.

How can *attach.bat* get the current directory location and write it to *run.txt*?

---

I know how to write to the txt files, but I can't find the current directory.
I want to be able to mount this from anywhere on the fly and any directory.

For example:

```
echo select vdisk file="C:\Max\maximus.vhd" >> C:\Max\run.txt
echo attach vdisk >> C:\Max\run.txt
```

Comment: @echo off
echo select vdisk file="%~dp0maximus.vhd"  >> %~dp0\run.txt
echo attach vdisk  >> %~dp0\run.txt
timeout /t 2 /nobreak
cd %~dp0
diskpart /s run.txt
yes this is working!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is using [%~dp0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/) to reference the drive and path of the batch file as [Anton Tykhyy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77724/anton-tykhyy) suggested.

```
@echo off
echo select vdisk file="%~dp0maximus.vhd" 1>"%~dp0run.txt"
echo attach vdisk 1>>"%~dp0run.txt"
timeout.exe /t 2 /nobreak
cd /D "%~dp0"
diskpart.exe /s run.txt
```