# How to find path to folder and put files inside?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, path-finding

I want to write a .bat script which finds a folder for installed program (e.g. Acrobat\JavaScript) because the folder can have a different path on every computer. Then put a .js file and a imgfolder inside. The .js file and the imgfolder is in the same folder as the .bat script. How can I find the full path of Acrobat\JavaScript on drive C and save to variable in order to copy the .js inside?

Here is what I tried:

```
@echo off

REM  find the folder with my .bat file 

for /f %%i in ("%0") do set curpath=%%~dpi 
echo  %curpath% 

REM it fails on this place:

for /R "C:\Programm Files(x86)" /D %d in (*) 
  do @if "%~nd" == "Acrobat\JavaScript" 

REM  I want to save here the path "%d" to a variable  in order to use it for copying

echo "%d"  

pause
```

If it works, I'll use this to copy imgfolder and the .js file to the retrieved path:

```
XCOPY %curpath%\imgFolder %d
```

To copy a folder:

```
XCOPY %curpath%\script.js %d /i
```

UPDATE:

I checked in the register, I found HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe Acrobat\
and then all the versions 9.0 - 11.0. As I understood the path is saved in the folder InstallPath, therefore I combined:

```
 "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Acrobat.exe" /v InstallPath') ...
```

Is it right?

```
 set path=""

 for /f "tokens=1-2*" %%A in ('reg query   "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Acrobat.exe" /v InstallPath') do (
 set path="%%C\JavaScript"
 )

echo path
pause

Error:
W:\batScript>for /F "tokens=1-2*" %A in ('reg query "HKLM\Software
\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Acrobat.exe" /v InstallPath') do (se
t path="%C\VBoxManage.ex" )
'reg' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I tried with reg.exe query, the same error. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: For folder path containing the batch file look at [What does %~dp0 mean, and how does it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076) And instead of searching for the folder, it is better to use `reg.exe query` to get the installation folder for Acrobat from registry from `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Acrobat.exe`. Use `regedit.exe` to see how application path of Acrobat is recorded in registry and run `reg.exe query /?` in a command prompt window to get help on this command.

Comment: `%%d`, not `%d` - like you did it with `%%i` already. (use single `%` only on command line outside of batchfiles)

Comment: Thanks Mofi and Stephan for the tips, I am progressed, but not much. Could you check my UPDATE above to say what it wrong?

Comment: don't use `%path%` as a user variable name. You overwrote the systemvariable `%PATH%` which tells windows, where to find it's applications. Therefore `reg.exe` is not found (because windows looks for it in the folders specified by `%PATH%`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error `'reg' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` in your code, because you have overwritten your system `path` by using the code `set path=""`. Never use a variable with the name `path` as it will mess up your default system path.

Try this piece of code to identify the adobe path.

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=2 tokens=*" %%i in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\AcroRd32.exe" /V path  2^>nul') do  (set "adobe_path=%%i")
set adobe_path=%adobe_path:path    REG_SZ    =%
echo %adobe_path%
```

Tested output -

```
D:\Scripts>type op.bat
@echo off
for /f "skip=2 tokens=*" %%i in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\AcroRd32.exe" /V path  2^>nul') do  (set "adobe_path=%%i")
set adobe_path=%adobe_path:path    REG_SZ    =%
echo %adobe_path%
D:\Scripts>
D:\Scripts>
D:\Scripts>op.bat
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\

D:\Scripts>
```

Cheers, 
G