# How to convert %~dp0 to bash

Tags: bash, shell, batch-file

I need to convert a batch file to a shell file to run it on Ubuntu. I'm new with bash scripting so would you please help me with a piece of the script?

My batch code is :

```
::Version detector
set Sverion=%~dp0\*.jar

FOR /f %%i IN ("%Sverion%") DO (
set SOver=%%~ni
)
```

Would you please explain what `set Sverion=%~dp0\*.jar` means and how I can convert it to shell?

Thank you,
Diana

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a Bash script tell what directory it's stored in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in)

Comment: @jeb I considered marking it as a duplicate of that but that assumes one knows the answer to the question being asked here; namely "What does `~dp0` do in a batch script?".

Comment: @EtanReisner That's right, but that's also easy to get by search [What does %~dp0 mean, and how does it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5034076/463115)

Comment: Then I'd mark it a dup of that ticket and add a comment for the bash one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation of `~dp0` can be found at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting#String_processing.

The [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) equivalent can be found at [How do I determine the location of my script? I want to read some config files from the same place.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) and also the first "Related" post listed in the sidebar of this post.