# Check if Windows batch variable starts with a specific string

Tags: variables, batch-file, if-statement

How can I find out (with Windows a batch command), if, for example, a variable starts with `ABC`?

I know that I can search for variables if I know the whole content (`if "%variable%"=="abc"`), but I want that it only looks after the beginning.

I also need it to find out where the batch file is located, so if there is a other command that reveals the file's location, please let me know.

Comment: @mario bash is not Windows batch.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use the [variable substring syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html):

```
IF "%variable:~0,3%"=="ABC" [...]
```

If you need the path to the batch file without the batch file name, you can use the variable:

```
%~dp0
```

Syntax for this is explained in the [help for the `for` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5034119/696808), although this variable syntax extends beyond just the `for` command syntax.

Comment: And 0,3% means it searches for the first 3 letters?

Comment: No, it gets the first three characters from the variable. Then the first characters are compared with "abc"

Comment: @EricRösch It's a substring.  It means "Starting with character 0 (the first) give me 3 characters".

Comment: Thank you, that's what I wanted to know.

Comment: Is it possible directly on %1 without `set variable=%1`? echo "%1:~0,2"
echo "%1:~0,2%"
echo "%%1:~0,2%"
echo "%%1:~0,2%%"
echo "%%%1:~0,2%"
echo "%%%1:~0,2%%"
echo "%%%%1:~0,2%"
: they all don't work.

Comment: @kxr Not as far as I'm aware.  Argument variables don't appear to support substrings, although I believe they do support [search and replace](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html).

Comment: But sometimes I don't know the length

Answer (score 3):

to find batch file location use `%0` (gives full patch to current batch file) or `%CD%` variable which gives local directory

Comment: And `%~dp0` gives just the drive and path, without the filename of the current batch file.