# Azure Cloud Service Startup task that needs to run a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cloud-services

All,

***Note:*** I have updated the question after some feedback.

Thanks to ***@jisaak*** for his help so far.

I have the need to run a PowerShell script that adds TCP bindings and some other stuff when I deploy my Cloud Service.

Here is my Cloud Service Project:

[image]

Here is my Cloud Service Project and Webrole project:
[image]

Here is my task in ServiceDefinition.csdef:[image]

And here is the PowerShell script I want to run:
[image]

here is my attempt at the Startup.cmd:
[image]

When I deploy I get this in the Azure log:
[image]

And this in the powershell log:
[image]

Any help would be very much appreciated.

I think I am nearly there but following other people syntax on the web doesn't seem to get me there.

thanks
Russ

Comment: if you are scheduling to execute the PS file or text file in power shell it doesn't work. I have observed it. However if you simply run the code on Azure PS platform it works. It is just an observation by me.

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is that the working directory of the batch command interpreter when it runs Startup.cmd runs is not as expected.

The Startup.cmd is located in the `\approot\bin\Startup` directory but the working directory is `\approot\bin`.

Therefore the command `.\RoleStartup.ps1` is not able to find the RoleStartup.ps1 as it is looking in the `bin` directory not in the `bin\Startup` directory.

Solutions I know to this are:

**Solution 1**:
Use `..\Startup\RoleStartup.ps1` to call the RoleStartup.ps1 from Startup.cmd.

**Soltuion 2**:
Change the current working directory in Startup.cmd so that the relative path `.\RoleStartup.ps1` is found. I do this by `CHDIR %~dp0` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work)) to change into the directory that contains Startup.cmd.

**Solution 3**:
As Don Lockhart's answer suggested, do not copy the Startup directory to the output, instead leave it set as "Content" in the Visual Studio project. This means the files within it will exist in the `\approot\Startup` directory on the Azure instance. (You would then want to make sure that the Startup folder is not publically accessible via IIS!). Then update the reference to Startup.cmd in ServiceDefinition.csdef to `..\Startup\Startup.cmd`, and update the reference to RoleStartup.ps1 in Startup.cmd to `..\Startup\RoleStartup.ps1`. This works on the fact that the working directory is `bin` and uses `..\Startup` to always locate the Startup directory relative to it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the executionpolicy within your cmd - just call the script. Also, you should use a relative path because you can't rely that there is `C` disk.

Change your batch to:

```
powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted -file .\RoleStartup.ps1
```

Right click on the `RoleStartup.ps1` and `Startup.cmd`in Visual Studio and ensure that the `Copy to Output directory` is set to `copy always`.

If this still doesn't work, remove the startup call in your `csdef`, deploy the service, rdp into it and try to invoke the script by yourself to retrieve any errors.

**Edit:**

Try to adopt your script as below:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

$site = $null

do # gets the first website until the result is not $null
{
    $site = Get-WebSite | select -first 1
    Sleep 1
}
until ($site)

# get the appcmd path
$appcmd = Join-Path ([System.Environment]::GetFolderPath('System')) 'inetsrv\appcmd.exe'

# ensure the appcmd.exe is present
if (-not (Test-Path $appcmd))
{
    throw "appcmd.exe not found in '$appcmd'"
}

# The rest of your script ....
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I have done everything you suggested. Even down to the RDP test of the script. The deployment passed, I can see that, in the PowerShell event log, it, at least new about my script but no settings were changed on the server. I then ran the script after RDPing in and it ran and settings were successfully changed. Please see my edits regarding event logs on the server.

Comment: This looks like a timing problem. You can try to change the `taskType` to `background` and adopt your powershell script (see my edited answer). The script now waits until there is a website. Also, the script uses the `GetFolderPath` function to determine the `system32` folder

Comment: I have not come back to this for a while but another article suggests I use the Windows Task Scheduler to schedule my task when it detects, in the Azure log, that IIS has been setup and started. http://www.ideliverable.com/blog/making-iis-configuration-changes-in-a-web-role-startup-task this works on the server when I run manually but not when running from Startup-task. So, ultimately I think the only issue I have is making my startup task call my cmd file which calls PowerShell The call to PowerShell always fails when using a startup task. Note, I have set the encoding of the file correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it easier in the past to not copy the content to the output directory.  I have approot\bin as the working directory.  My startUp task element's commandLine attribute uses a relative reference to the .cmd file like so:

[image]

The .cmd file references the PowerShell script relatively from the working directory as well:

```
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -f ..\StartUp\RoleStartup.ps1
```

Comment: just one thing, I don't have an App_Start folder anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

So I am coming back to this after many different attempts to make it work. 
I have tried using:

- Startup config in the ServiceDefinition.csdef
- I have tried registering a scheduled task on the server that scans the Windows Azure log looking for [System[Provider[@Name='Windows Azure Runtime 2.6.0.0'] and EventID=10004]]

Nothing worked either due to security or the timing of events and IIS not being fully setup yet.

So I finally bit the bullet and used my Webrole.cs => public override bool OnStart() method:
[image]

Combined with this in the ServiceDefinition.csdef:
[image]

Now it all works. This was **not** the most satisfying result as some of the other ways to do it felt more elegant. Also, many others posted that they got the other ways of doing it to work. Maybe I would have got there eventually but my time was restricted.

thanks
Russ