# Open a .bat file, out of a folder, off a flashdrive

Tags: batch-file

I have a game that I'm making off of my flashdrive, and I'm trying to make a save feature into an RPG game.  I know I can just save all the data into a character bat file, and then call that bat file, but the problem is that my flashdrive looks cluttered whenever multiple characters get formed.  understand?  I need to beable to load a save, from a character folder (for organization) from a changing source folder, (Because the flashdrive will be in different USB ports, such as :E or :F etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You can determine the drive that a Windows batch file uses by using the CMD variable substitutions.  Within a batch file, you can determine where the file resides.

`%~d0` is the drive.  `%~dp0` is the directory.  And there are more.

See [What does %~dp0 mean, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work)