# How to make a batch file echo its name to a text document?

Tags: batch-file, echo

I want my batch file to echo its filename into a text document.

I tried:

```
echo %~f0>"%userprofile%\Desktop\test\test.txt"
```

But instead of saying only its filename, it also says the directory that it's in.

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.bat
```

Comment: The title says something different than the question body, so please update accordingly!

Comment: More interesting, that someone who already found the `%~f` modifier (which is quite hard to find for a newbie) seems not to be able to find the other ones.

Answer (score 3):

Use `%~n0` or `%~nx0` in place of `%~f0` depending on what your interpretation of `name` is.

See

```
for /? |more
```

from the prompt for documentation

Answer (score 1):

To get the *filename* and *extension*, use `%~nx0`. For a [complete list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5034119/5269570) of variable references, see `for /?`

**For example:**

```
echo %~nx0 > "%userprofile%\Desktop\test\test.txt"
```

Would output:

> test.bat